# Which type of sorting is used in the std::sort()?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Can anyone please tell me that which type of sorting technique (bubble, insertion, selection, quick, merge, count...) is implemented in the `std::sort()` function defined in the `<algorithm>` header file?

Comment: Not your question, but it says here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ that is nlogn on average and n^2 worst case (which goes the same for quicksort).

Comment: MSVC help also states that "The average of a sort complexity is O(N log N), where N = _Last – _First."

Comment: BTW-- The answer for the c standard library function `sort()` is the same: something that runs at `O(N log N)`. Sometimes that manpage will tell you what your system is actually using.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Most implementations of `std::sort` use quicksort, (or usually a hybrid algorithm like introsort, which combines quicksort, heapsort and insertion sort).

The only thing the standard requires is that `std::sort` somehow sort the data according to the specified ordering with a complexity of approximately O(N log(N)); it is not guaranteed to be stable.  Technically, introsort better meets the complexity requirement than quicksort, because quicksort has quadratic worst-case time.

Comment: Do you any quicksorting implementation of `std::sort`? The ones I've seen all use the introsort from the original STL. Per C++11, the O(n lg n) requirement is no longer "approximate".

Comment: Also (at least in visual studio) there seems to be an optimization to perform counting sort for small ranged numbers. I have not read the implementation, but I know sorting is linear for more than a million numbers in range of about 1 million.

Comment: I've never seen an implementation that doesn't use introsort. You should either back up the "Most implementations…" claim or amend your answer.

Comment: I gave a similar answer below with more details on introsort. Also, I think that introsort was always the "standard STL implementation" of std::sort from the beginning (and not quicksort).

Answer (score 10):

C++ Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2003

> **25.3.1.1 sort**
>
> ```
> template<class RandomAccessIterator>
>    void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
> template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
>    void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
>           Compare comp);
> ```
>
> 1 **Effects**: Sorts the elements in the
>   range [first, last).
>
> 2 **Complexity**:
>   Approximately N log N (where N == last
>   - first) comparisons on the average.

There is no information about method but *complexity* is always `N log N`.

Comment: Your text and the quote don't match. N log N is on average, but it doesn't say anything about worst case.

Answer (score 7):

There are three algorithms that are used in MSVC2013 STL, referring to the source code of `std::sort`.

> It is most likely to use `QuickSort`, or a variation over `QuickSort` called `IntroSort`.
>
> If the recursion goes too deep, the `HeapSort` will be used here.
>
> Otherwise `InsertSort` will be used.

Answer (score 5):

Probably all implementations of `std::sort` use *introsort* (aka *introspection sort*), a hybrid algorithm that combines quicksort and heapsort. Actually, *introsort* was particularly invented in 1997 for the purpose of a performant sort implemenation in C++ STL.

The only thing the standard requires is that `std::sort` somehow sort the data according to the specified ordering with a complexity of *O(N log(N))*; it is not guaranteed to be stable (there is a separate `std::stable_sort` algorithms available, if this should be required).

Technically, introsort better meets the complexity requirement than quicksort: This is because heapsort has guaranteed *O(N log(N))* complexity in the worst case, whereas quicksort has quadratic worst-case time.

However, heapsort is 'slower' than quicksort in the average case, in the sense that heapsort performs *C*N log(N)* whereas quicksort has *D*N log(n)* performance, with *D* being significantly smaller than *C* (the numbers *C* and *D* are constants). In other words, the per-comparison-overhead of heapsort is higher than the one of quicksort.

To get the best of both worlds, introsort starts with quicksort —a recursive algorithm—, but when recursion depth gets too high (which means it gets into a *degenerated* worst-case behaviour), it switches to heapsort.

See also [the Wikipedia entry for introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) or the [original paper](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/gp/introsort.ps) from David Musser, who invented introsort particularly for STL.

Comment: I based my answer on that of https://stackoverflow.com/users/168288/charles-salvia. I first try to update/modify/edit his response, but moderators suggested to provide a seperate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**GCC 9.2.0 libstdc++ source confirming introsort**

Others [have mentioned introsort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1840131/895245), but here is some evidence for libstc++, which is the default C++ implementation on most Linux distros.

libstdc++ is a part of GCC itself, so we will look into GCC source.

[libstdc++-v3/include/std/algorithm](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-9_2_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/algorithm) is the main header and contains:

```
#include <bits/stl_algobase.h>
#include <bits/stl_algo.h>
```

Then, [bits/stl_algo.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-9_2_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L4818) contains the definition of the sort overloads, one of them being:

```
  /**
   *  @brief Sort the elements of a sequence.
   *  @ingroup sorting_algorithms
   *  @param  __first   An iterator.
   *  @param  __last    Another iterator.
   *  @return  Nothing.
   *
   *  Sorts the elements in the range @p [__first,__last) in ascending order,
   *  such that for each iterator @e i in the range @p [__first,__last-1),  
   *  *(i+1)<*i is false.
   *
   *  The relative ordering of equivalent elements is not preserved, use
   *  @p stable_sort() if this is needed.
  */
  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator>
    inline void
    sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last)
    {
      // concept requirements
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_Mutable_RandomAccessIteratorConcept<
        _RandomAccessIterator>)
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_LessThanComparableConcept<
        typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>)
      __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
      __glibcxx_requires_irreflexive(__first, __last);

      std::__sort(__first, __last, __gnu_cxx::__ops::__iter_less_iter());
    }
```

so we see that this just does a bunch of sanity checks on the input, and then calls `std::__sort` which is [defined in the same file](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-9_2_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1962):

```
  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Compare>
    inline void
    __sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
       _Compare __comp)
    {
      if (__first != __last)
    {
      std::__introsort_loop(__first, __last,
                std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
                __comp);
      std::__final_insertion_sort(__first, __last, __comp);
    }
    }
```

and I'll stop here that we have reached an identifier called `std::__introsort_loop`, the rest of the implementation is on the same file is anyone still has doubts.

It should also be possible to GDB step debug into `std::sort` without any further setup in Ubuntu 18.04 as mentioned for `std::set` at: [What is the underlying data structure of a STL set in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558153/what-is-the-underlying-data-structure-of-a-stl-set-in-c/51944661#51944661)

**C++17 parallel sorting**

We now also have parallel sorting, so it would be worth looking on how it is done as well: [Are C++17 Parallel Algorithms implemented already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031060/are-c17-parallel-algorithms-implemented-already/55989883#55989883)

As mentioned in the above answer, the implementation relies on an external library: Intel Thread Building Blocks: https://github.com/intel/tbb

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean std::sort?  If so it can be implemented any way they want.  Its probably Quick sort but could be radix or something else.  As long as it produces you a sorted list in at least O(n log n) the implementation is fine, afaik.

Comment: There is also a complexity requirement, that the algorithm be O(n log n).  This isn't much of a restriction, since almost all common sorts meet this requerment.  Is does prevent the use of Bogo sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogo_sort).

Comment: I suppose radix sort *isn't* allowed, (even though it might be efficient for certain data types) since it does not have logarithmic complexity, as it isn't base on comparisons.

Comment: oh right?  So if it did a O(1) that would be against the rules as well? (Ignoring the impossibility of such an algorithm).

Comment: @Goz No, an O(1) implementation would be fine.  The requirements are an upper bound on the complexity.  They are generally set to the most efficient know implementation, but don't preclude some new data structure or algorithm that is more efficient.

Comment: `std::sort` is comparison-based, which inherently prevents implementations faster than O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

Just some empirical results:

I translated a python script using numpy 1.9.2 sort to C++ using std::sort (VS2008 toolchain).

I only get the same exact results in the python and C++ sides when I use numpy.sort argument kind='mergesort'. I get different relative ordering for elements with same key when kind='quicksort' or kind='heapsort'. So I guess that at least for the version of STL that comes with VS2008 std::sort uses mergesort.