# What is the underlying data structure of a STL set in C++?

Tags: c++, set

I would like to know how a set is implemented in C++. If I were to implement my own set container without using the STL provided container, what would be the best way to go about this task?

I understand STL sets are based on the abstract data structure of a binary search tree. So what is the underlying data structure? An array?

Also, how does `insert()` work for a set? How does the set check whether an element already exists in it?

I read on wikipedia that another way to implement a set is with a hash table. How would this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could implement a binary search tree by first defining a `Node` struct:

```
struct Node
{
  void *nodeData;
  Node *leftChild;
  Node *rightChild;
}
```

Then, you could define a root of the tree with another `Node *rootNode;`

The Wikipedia entry on [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) has a pretty good example of how to implement an insert method, so I would also recommend checking that out.

In terms of duplicates, they are generally not allowed in sets, so you could either just discard that input, throw an exception, etc, depending on your specification.

Comment: As far as i know, std::set is an ordered container. If its a BST how can traversing be ordered ?

Comment: @Shasha99, a pre-order traverse will give you the elements in ordered.

Comment: @MASh we i guess talk about the order of insertion.

Comment: @Shasha99 order of insertion is not what "ordered" in "ordered container" refers to.

Comment: In order to meet the performance specs promised by the standard, one needs a *balanced* binary search tree.

Answer (score 47):

**Step debug into `g++` 6.4 stdlibc++ source**

Did you know that on Ubuntu's 16.04 default `g++-6` package or a [GCC 6.4 build from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-piece-by-piece-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf-without-shared-libra) you can step into the C++ library without any further setup?

By doing that we easily conclude that a Red-black tree used in this implementation.

This makes sense, since `std::set` can be traversed in order, which would not be efficient in if a hash map were used.

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int> s;
    s.insert(1);
    s.insert(2);
    assert(s.find(1) != s.end());
    assert(s.find(2) != s.end());
    assert(s.find(3) == s3.end());
}
```

Compile and debug:

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -O0 -o main.out main.cpp
gdb -ex 'start' -q --args main.out
```

Now, if you step into `s.insert(1)` you immediately reach `/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_set.h`:

```
487 #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
488       std::pair<iterator, bool>
489       insert(value_type&& __x)
490       {
491     std::pair<typename _Rep_type::iterator, bool> __p =
492       _M_t._M_insert_unique(std::move(__x));
493     return std::pair<iterator, bool>(__p.first, __p.second);
494       }
495 #endif
```

which clearly just forwards to `_M_t._M_insert_unique`.

So we open the source file in vim and find the definition of `_M_t`:

```
      typedef _Rb_tree<key_type, value_type, _Identity<value_type>,
           key_compare, _Key_alloc_type> _Rep_type;
       _Rep_type _M_t;  // Red-black tree representing set.
```

So `_M_t` is of type `_Rep_type` and `_Rep_type` is a `_Rb_tree`.

OK, now that is enough evidence for me. If you don't believe that `_Rb_tree` is a Black-red tree, step a bit further and read the algorithm.

**`unordered_set` uses hash table**

Same procedure, but replace `set` with `unordered_set` on the code.

This makes sense, since `std::unordered_set` cannot be traversed in order, so the standard library chose hash map instead of Red-black tree, since hash map has a better amortized insert time complexity.

Stepping into `insert` leads to `/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unordered_set.h`:

```
415       std::pair<iterator, bool>
416       insert(value_type&& __x)
417       { return _M_h.insert(std::move(__x)); }
```

So we open the source file in `vim` and search for `_M_h`:

```
      typedef __uset_hashtable<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>  _Hashtable;
      _Hashtable _M_h;
```

So hash table it is.

**`std::map` and `std::unordered_map`**

Analogous for `std::set` vs `std:unordered_set`: [What data structure is inside std::map in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414579/stdmap-what-data-structure-is-inside/51945119#51945119)

**Performance characteristics**

You could also infer the data structure used by timing them:

[image]

Graph generation procedure and Heap vs BST analysis and at: [Heap vs Binary Search Tree (BST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147242/heap-vs-binary-search-tree-bst/29548834#29548834)

We clearly see for:

- `std::set`, a logarithmic insertion time
- `std::unordered_set`, a more complex hashmap pattern:

  - on the non-zoomed plot, we clearly see the backing dynamic array doubling on huge one off linearly increasing spikes
  - on the zoomed plot, we see that the times are basically constant and going towards 250ns, therefore much faster than the `std::map`, except for very small map sizes

    Several strips are clearly visible, and their inclination becomes smaller whenever the array doubles.

    I believe this is due to average linearly increasing linked list walks withing each bin. Then when the array doubles, we have more bins, so shorter walks.

Comment: "By doing that we easily conclude that a Red-black tree used." *...by this implementation*. Implementations are given latitude in exactly how they implement *many* parts of the standard

Answer (score 32):

As KTC said, how `std::set` is implemented can vary -- the C++ standard simply specifies an abstract data type. In other words, the standard does not specify how a container should be implemented, just what operations it is required to support. However, most implementations of the STL do, as far as I am aware, use [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) or other balanced binary search trees of some kind (GNU libstdc++, for instance, uses red-black trees).

While you could theoretically implement a set as a hash table and get faster asymptotic performance (amortized O(key length) versus O(log n) for lookup and insert), that would require having the user supply a hash function for whatever type they wanted to store (see [Wikipedia's entry on hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for a good explanation of how they work). As for an implementation of a binary search tree, you wouldn't want to use an array -- as Raul mentioned, you would want some kind of `Node` data structure.

Comment: You can implement *a* set type with a hash table.  However, you can't (at least not easily) implement one that meets the requirements for std::set iterators.

Comment: @dan04: you can't even implement one that satisfies the requirements for std::set lookup and insert. As Toli says, you need a hash function on the key type, and the user of `std::set` isn't required by the standard to provide one. So when their code fails to compile with `no match found for hash(MyElement)`, that means the std::set implementation is defective.

Comment: Hashtable is unlikely because `std::set` is sorted.

Comment: I'd like to see an implementation that can synthesize a hash from an arbitrary `Compare`, and maintain the complexity requirements of `std::set`

Comment: @Caleth I believe you can do that as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件 No, that's talking about using a `Compare` that isn't `std::less`, not conjuring a `std::size_t(T)` from a `bool(T, T)`

Answer (score 9):

> I understand STL sets are based on the abstract data structure of a binary search tree. 
>   So what is the underlying data structure? An array?

As others have pointed out, it varies. A set is commonly implemented as a tree (red-black tree, balanced tree, etc.) though but there may be other implementations that exist.

> Also, how does insert() work for a
>   set?

It depends on the underlying implementation of your set. If it is implemented as a binary tree, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) has a sample recursive implementation for the insert() function. You may want to check it out.

> How does the set check whether an
>   element already exists in it?

If it is implemented as a tree, then it traverses the tree and check each element. However, sets do not allow duplicate elements to be stored though. If you want a set that allows  duplicate elements, then you need a multiset.

> I read on wikipedia that another way
>   to implement a set is with a hash
>   table. How would this work?

You may be referring to a hash_set, where the set is implemented using hash tables. You'll need to provide a hash function to know which location to store your element. This implementation is ideal when you want to be able to search for an element quickly. However, if it is important for your elements to be stored in particular order, then the tree implementation is more appropriate since you can traverse it preorder, inorder or postorder.

Answer (score 8):

How a particular container is implemented in C++ is entirely implementation dependent. All that is required is for the result to meet the requirements set out in the standard, such as complexity requirement for the various methods, iterators requirements etc.

Comment: That said, most (all?) are red-black trees.

Comment: There's an AVL based implementation at http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlavlmap/ and an incomplete BTree based implementation at http://idlebox.net/2007/stx-btree/

Comment: Given the time-complexity constrains and the requirement that it has to be sorted, there's not much room for alternatives that won't involve some kind of balanced tree.

Comment: The complexity requirements are usually specified with a particular implementation in mind, and as such can be quite restrictive on the choice of data structure.

Answer (score 1):

[cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

> Sets are usually implemented as red-black trees.

I checked, and both `libc++` and `libstdc++` do use red-black trees for `std::set`.

`std::unordered_set` was implemented with a hash table in `libc++` and I presume the same for `libstdc++` but didn't check.

**Edit:** Apparently my word is not good enough.

- `libc++`: [1](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/set#L430) [2](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__tree#L55)
- `libstdc++`: [1](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h#L133)

Comment: I have confirmed that by step debugging into `libstdc++`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51944661/895245 since I only believe it from GDB itself :-)

Answer (score 1):

Chiming in on this, because I did not see anyone explicitly mention it... The C++ standard *does not* specify the data structure to use for std::set and std::map. What it does however specify is the run-time complexity of various operations. The requirements on computational complexity for the insert, delete and find operations more-or-less force an implementation to use a balanced tree algorithm.

There are two common algorithms for implementing balanced binary trees: Red-Black and AVL. Of the two, Red-Black is a little bit simpler of an implementation, requiring 1 less bit of storage per tree node (which hardly matters, since you're going to burn a byte on it in a simple implementation anyway), and is a little bit faster than AVL on node deletions (this is due to a more relaxed requirement on the balancing of the tree).

All of this, combined with std::map's requirement that the key & datum are stored in an std::pair force this all upon you without explicitly naming the data structure you must use for the container.

This all, in turn is compounded by the c++14/17 supplemental features to the container that allow splicing of nodes from one tree into another.