# How to have a set of structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct, set

I have a struct which has a unique key. I want to insert instances of these structs into a set. I know that to do this the < operator has to be overloaded so that set can make a comparison in order to do the insertion.

The following does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
struct foo 
{
      int key;
};

bool operator<(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)
{
      return lhs.key < rhs.key;
}

set<foo> bar;

int main()
{
    foo *test = new foo;
    test->key = 0;
    bar.insert(test);
}
```

Comment: test.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<foo, std::less<foo>, std::allocator<foo> >::insert(foo*&)’

Error seems pretty clear to me. Your trying to put a pointer where an object should be.

Comment: Being able to edit a question is nice but you shouldn't change its meaning doing so. This invalidates any (possibly correct) answer and forces future readers to look at the edit first. There is no limitation on StackOverflow regarding a same person posting several questions within a short amount of time. Actually, that's even a good idea.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This might help:

```
struct foo
{
  int key;
};

inline bool operator<(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)
{
  return lhs.key < rhs.key;
}
```

If you are using namespaces, it is a good practice to declare the `operator<()` function in the same namespace.

---

For the sake of completeness after your edit, and as other have pointed out, you are trying to add a `foo*` where a `foo` is expected.

If you really want to deal with pointers, you may wrap the `foo*` into a smart pointer class (`auto_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, ...).

But note that in both case, you loose the benefit of the overloaded `operator<` which operates on `foo`, not on `foo*`.

Comment: That works but not when inserting into a set. I changed my question to include the code.

Comment: This answers the original question, I suggest it be chosen as correct, the adapted question was simply a syntax error.

Comment: I loved the fact that you used the keyword [`inline`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson13.html) in your functions, which boosts up performance! +1

Comment: @AK_ Actually it has little to do with performance but rather with allowing this definition in the header file, in regards to the One Definition Rule. I expect any decent compiler to inline this with or without the `inline` directive.

Comment: @ereOn I agree with what you stated but I think performance is also one of the main goals behind `inline`

Comment: @AK_: It was at some point but I don't believe that statement holds with modern compilers which are free to inline or not regardless of the `inline` directive.

Comment: I have a question, why does this operator overloading only works when defined outside struct? When I defined it inside it wasnt working, throwing error '<' operator not defined??

Answer (score 9):

```
struct Blah
{
    int x;
};

bool operator<(const Blah &a, const Blah &b)
{
    return a.x < b.x;
}

...

std::set<Blah> my_set;
```

However, I don't like overloading `operator<` unless it makes intuitive sense (does it really make sense to say that one `Blah` is "less than" another `Blah`?).  If not, I usually provide a custom comparator function instead:

```
bool compareBlahs(const Blah &a, const Blah &b)
{
    return a.x < b.x;
}

...

std::set<Blah,compareBlahs> my_set;
```

Comment: I like the explicit compare function, but it did not compile for me. This is what I did instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/43187783/4876817

Answer (score 8):

You can overload the `operator <` inside the class also as,

```
struct foo 
{
  int key;
  bool operator < (const foo &other) const { return key < other.key; }
};
```

In your question, if you want to use `set<foo> bar;` as declaration then, you should insert value as,

```
bar.insert(*test);
```

But that won't be a good idea, as you are making redundant copy.

Comment: >.> doesn't actually work for std::unordered_set though.

Answer (score 2):

see ereOn's answer, it's right.

The real problem in you code is this:

```
foo *test = new foo;
test->key = 0;
bar.insert(test);
```

You insert a **pointer** in the set, not a struct. Change the `insert` to:

```
 bar.insert( *test );
 //          ^
```

---

EDIT: but then you'll need to `delete foo`, as it will be copied in the `set`. Or just create it on the stack (using `set` with pointers is not a good idea, because the arrangement will be "strange" - the `set` will sort according to the pointers' addresses )

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to give foo a constructor:

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int k) : key(k) { }
    int key;
};
```

Then to add, rather than...

```
foo *test = new foo;
test->key = 0;
bar.insert(test);   // BROKEN - need to dereference ala *test
// WARNING: need to delete foo sometime...
```

...you can simply use:

```
bar.insert(foo(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't in your set; it's in your `test` object. You're using Java style there. In C++, we just write:

```
set<foo> bar;

int main()
{
    foo test; // Local variable, goes out of scope at }
    test.key = 0;
    bar.insert(test); // Insert _a copy of test_ in bar.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In c++11 we can use a lambda expression, I used this way which is similar to what @Oliver was given.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Blah
{
    int x;
};



int main(){

    auto cmp_blah = [](Blah lhs, Blah rhs) { return lhs.x < rhs.x;};

    std::set<Blah, decltype(cmp_blah)> my_set(cmp_blah);

    Blah b1 = {2};
    Blah b2 = {2};
    Blah b3 = {3};

    my_set.insert(b1);
    my_set.insert(b2);
    my_set.insert(b3);

    for(auto const& bi : my_set){
        std::cout<< bi.x << std::endl;
    }

}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14a48ae83b8c9d4b)