# Find item in set of struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I have set of a struct.

```
struct Neighbour
{
int  ID;
int  Left;
int  Right;
}

set<NodeNeighbour>NextDoor;
```

How do I find an item in this set were ID=='number to search'?

With a straigth forward set one can find an item simply with set.find(). 
Is there something simular for searching a set of struct?

Thx in advance

Comment: You're probably looking for a custom set comparator. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816658/how-to-have-a-set-of-structs-in-c

Answer (score 6):

You can use `std::find_if`, which uses a unary predicate function:

```
auto result = std::find_if(std::begin(NextDoor), std::end(NextDoor), [numberToSearch] (const auto & n) {
    return n.ID == numberToSearch;
});
```

`result` will be an iterator pointing at the first element found.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find for more details and examples.

Comment: Aw dang seconds late. +1 I would just go for `auto` for lambda param.

Comment: @Happy The remove from `auto result = ...` =P. Just a little idea.

Comment: Sorry, tag should have been C++11 Just amended it

Comment: yes was gonna do just that, even though auto types are just so much more convenient to type that I tend to forget that pre-C++11 even existed :)

Comment: @SirDarius,  What if the ID is not unique and therefore could be in the set more than once? How do I retrieve all items were ID==numberToSearch?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to do an operation on every matching member, a simple loop may do, or std::for_each. If you want to populate another set with the matching data, you can use std::copy_if. Or even continue calling find using the returned iterator as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `set`, use a `map<int,NeighBour>` and use the `ID` as a key.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

See an example use:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at