# std::set constructor second argument error

Tags: c++, set, codeblocks

**Codeblocks** raises an **error** on this line :

```
set<string,cmpi> m;
```

Where the **cmpi** function is :

```
int cmpi(string one , string two )
{
    one = toLowerCase(one); 
    two = toLowerCase(two);

    if(two == one) 
        return 0;
    else 
    if (one < two ) 
        return -1;
    else 
        return 1;
}
```

**It says (the ERROR) :**

> `type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::set'`

***Is there something with the return value of my cmpi function or is it something else ?***

Comment: You have to supply a functor name, not a function's name. A functor is demonstrated in this question, which is the same problem as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator. As an aside, your `cmpi` does what `std::string`'s overloaded comparison operators already do, so you don't need to supply a comparator.

Comment: @birryree: No, his compare function makes the strings lowercase before comparing them. That isn't the same at all.

Comment: @Zan - whoops...someone needs sleep. Thanks.

Comment: Although you can use a function pointer, the type that you would want would be something like `std::set<std::string, bool(*)(std::string, std::string)>`. However, you need to proved a comparsion that does the job of "less than", not a three way +1/0/-1 style comparison so your compare should be returning `true` if `one < two` and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

> **type/value** mismatch

Indeed. 
`std::set` expects a **type**, not a function pointer (**value**):

```
int cmpi(string one, string two);

typedef int cmpi_t(string one, string two); // the type of cmpi

std::set<string, cmpi_t*> m (&cmpi);
```

Comment: You either need `typedef int (*cmpi_t)(string, string);` or `std::set<string, cmpi_t*>`. The function template argument can't be a function type, it must be a pointer to function type.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Obviously, a star was missing somewhere. (I am ashamed.)

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter has to be a type.  You can create a type for your function like this:

```
struct CmpI {
  bool operator()(const string &a,const string &b) { return cmpi(a,b)<0; }
};
```

Comment: The second parameter has to be a type, but he doesn't have to use a functor, a function pointer type is an acceptable template parameter for `std::set`'s comparison function.

Comment: @CharlesBailey A function ptr is not a Functor?

Comment: @curiousguy: Not in conventional usage in C++.

Comment: If the operator is not `const`, you cannot use a member comparator in a `const` member function, except by copying it.