# Error in custom struct set declaration

Tags: c++, struct, set

I'm getting a weird compiler error and as I'm new to using set's with custom struct's I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.

I'm trying to create a set of "pair's" and am using a custom comparison function for inserting said pair's.

```
struct pairT {
    std::string first, second;
};

int PairCmp(pairT &one, pairT &two) {
    if (one.first < two.first && one.second == two.second) return 0;
    else if (one.first < two.first) return -1;
    else if (one.first == two.first && one.second < two.second) return -1;
    return 1;
}

std::set<pairT> CartesianProduct (std::set<std::string> &one, std::set<std::string> &two) {
    std::set<pairT> returnSet(PairCmp);
    /.../
```

I'm getting the error from the last line of code:
C2664 "can't convert parameter 1 from int to const std::less... blah, blah, blah.

Any suggestions as to why I'm getting my ass kicked?

Comment: This answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator. Likely a duplicate, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using objects (instead of pointers) requires that you name a second template parameter for `std::set` used to compare two objects of `pairT`. See [`std::less<>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/less/) for an example.

Also, what you're trying here seems to be wrong. You're trying to return a `std::set` in `CartesianProduct()`, but the returned `PairCmp()` returns an integer.

Comment: thanks Mario- 
are you talking about a second parameter in that last line?  What would that be?

Comment: No, in the template argument list. But you won't need one if you overload `operator <` for your struct. But the immediate mistake is the error I added to the answer, you're essentially trying to return an integer as a `std::set`.