# Set of tuples (i, v) such that all tuples have different values of i

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to construct a set of tuples `(i, v)`, where `i` is an `int` and `v` is a `double`. The set cannot contain two tuples with the same value of `i`.

To do this, I think I should use a `std::set` of `std:tuple`s. Something like:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

set<tuple<int, double>> mySet;
```

The `std::set` class allows me to specify a comparator, and I think I should use this to avoid different tuples with the same value of `i`, but I don't know how to do it??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator

Comment: Sounds like `map<int, double>` to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're right! I didn't know about `map`. But I'd still like to understand how to do this with `set`

Answer (score 3):

`std::tuple` already provides a `operator<` that you can use for comparisons, but it compares *all* elements of the tuple. You simply need to provide a comparator that compares the first element of the tuple and ignores the second.

```
struct comparator
{
    bool operator()(const tuple<int, double> & lhs, const tuple<int, double> &  rhs)
    {
        return get<0>(lhs) < get<0>(rhs);
    }
};
```

Comment: but how do I make `set` use the comparator I implemented?

Comment: @becko you just add a second template parameter to the set: `set<tuple<int,double>,comparator> mySet`.

Comment: when I do this, I get an 'Error: function template "comparator" is not a type name'.

Comment: @becko, sorry - every time I've needed a functor a plain function was able to work. I've made an edit that should work better.

Answer (score 2):

A map may be a better choice `std::map<int, double>`. The interesting thing is that the `value_type` of the map is `std::pair<const int, double>` which can be used like a tuple : `std::get` ...