# Comparison function for sorting std::set<std::pair<int,std::pair<int,int>>>

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

I have these structures:

```
typedef std::pair<unsigned int, std::pair<int, int> > myPair;
typedef std::set< myPair> Graph;

Graph g;
```

What is the right comparison function for sorting the graph like?

```
std::sort(g.begin(), g.end(), Cmp());
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
struct Cmp{
    bool operator()(const myPair& l, const myPair& r)const{
        return l.second.second < r.second.second;
    }
};
```

I want the set to be ordered according to the second element of the most inner pair. Is it possible?

```
a = (std::make_pair(0,std::make_pair(1,1)));
b = (std::make_pair(0,std::make_pair(1,2)));
c = (std::make_pair(0,std::make_pair(1,0)));
d = (std::make_pair(1,std::make_pair(2,0)));
```

The result would be:

Before the ordering

```
c = (0,(1,0)), a = (0,(1,1)), b = (0,(1,2)), d = (1,(2,0)
```

After the ordering

```
c = (0,(1,0)), d = (1,(2,0), a = (0,(1,1)), b = (0,(1,2))
```

Question: Is it possible to create the set in this ordering manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison function is a good start. What is missing is "tie resolution". You need to specify what happens when `l.second.second == r.second.second`, and also what happens when `l.second.first == r.second.first`:

```
bool operator()(const myPair& l, const myPair& r)const{
    return (l.second.second < r.second.second) ||
           ((l.second.second == r.second.second) && (l.second.first < r.second.first)) ||
           ((l.second.second == r.second.second) && (l.second.first == r.second.first) && (l.first < r.first)).
}
```

- The first condition comes from your implementation.
- The second condition tells what to do when the first-priority items are equal to each other
- The third condition tells what to do when both the first-priority and the second-priority items are equal to each other.

In order to use this function for ordering your set, you need to pass it as the second template parameter to `std::set`. [Here is a Q&A explaining how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2620889/335858).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `std::sort` on `std::set`, but you can construct `set` with predicate.

```
typedef std::set<myPair, Cmp> Graph;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need another `set` with a different predicate. You can't change the sorting algorithm of an existing `set`.