# C++: using std::find on a set of class pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, find, std

I have a set of pointers to a custom class myClass:

`set<myClass*> s;`

I'm trying to use `std::find` to verify whether an object `O` of type `myClass *` is contained within the set, but this doesn't appear to be working- I think `find` might only work for objects and not pointers to objects? Is there any way to make this work? I tried dereferencing the pointer but then I realized that obviously wouldn't work since my `set` is one of pointers to objects anyway.

```
set<myClass*> s;
/* set gets filled up with objects of type myClass */
myClass *O = new myClass();
if(s.find(O) != s.end())
    cout<<"Found!\n";
```

I've manually printed out the members of `O` and an object already in the set, and I know they're identical. So this code should be printing "Found!" But it's not.

Comment: Please post the code you're having trouble with.  Thanks!

Comment: Logarithmic `std::set::find` would be more efficient than linear `std::find`.

Comment: Are you sure the object `O` you're looking for is a pointer, of type `myClass*` as stated, and not an instance of `myClass`?

Comment: Yes. I posted some sample code to clarify.

Comment: You don;t seem to be adding the pointer to the set...

Comment: You obviously aren't using `std::find`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a set of **pointers**, and you don't add your pointer in the set, so it is not found.

Following will found your pointer:

```
std::set<myClass*> s;
/* set gets filled up with objects of type myClass */
myClass *O = new myClass();
s.insert(O); // O added in set.
if (s.find(O) != s.end())
    cout<<"Found!\n"; // will be found
```

Else you may use a custom comparer.

Assuming you have `bool operator < (const myClass& lhs, const myClass& rhs)`

you may do

```
struct myClassComp {
    bool operator() (const myClass* lhs, const myClass* rhs) const
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};
```

and then

```
std::set<myClass*, myClassComp> s;
myClass O1;
s.insert(&O1);
myClass O2;

if (s.find(O2) != s.end())
    std::cout << "Found!\n"; // will be found
```

Comment: I am inserting my objects into the set, I just didn't include those lines of code because they are located elsewhere. That first example is exactly what I'm doing, and it does not work. I've tried both creating a custom comparator and overriding the == operator to make sure my class comparisons are correct, and neither helps.

Comment: In your snippet, you cannot have add `O` (pointer), you may have add an other pointer on a default `myClass`. Anyway, you compare pointer, not value.

Answer (score 0):

A set of pointer is organized by address of inserted objects, not the contents of the object. So looking in the set for `O` is looking in the set for an object with the address `O` points at. Since computers typically do not allow two objects to be at the same memory location, you will never find `O`.

For example you have strings O and P. O and P are initialized to the same value, "Hello world!" but are different objects and have different addresses.

You have `set<string*> myset;` and you insert P into the set `myset.insert(&P);`. So far everything is groovy.

But when you try and find `O` in myset you can't because the set is not trying to find "Hello World!", it is looking for `&O` and `&O` is not `&P`.

So you need to compare `O` and `P`, not `&O` and `&P`.

And at this point, I direct your attention here: [Using custom std::set comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator)