# typedef function is not a type name?

Tags: c++, function, types, header, std

This is my code inside `myCode.h`:

```
#include <set>

using namespace std;

bool MyObjectComp(const MyObject& lhs, const MyObject& rhs) {
    return lhs.mTick < rhs.mTick;
}

typedef std::multiset<MyObject, MyObjectComp> MyObjectMultiSet;
```

but it says that function `MyObjectComp` is not a type name. Where should I place it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom std::set comparator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template parameter for `std::multiset` expects a type,  `MyObjectComp` is not a type but is instead a function name.  You can either use `decltype` to get its type like

```
typedef std::multiset<MyObject, decltype(MyObjectComp)*> MyObjectMultiSet;
```

Or you could specify the type yourself like

```
typedef std::multiset<MyObject, bool(*)(const MyObject&, const MyObject&)> MyObjectMultiSet;
```

Also note the generally a functor/lambda is more efficent than using a function as the compiler can more easily optimize the code.  I would suggest using

```
struct MyObjectComp {
    bool operator()(const MyObject& lhs, const MyObject& rhs) {
        return lhs.mTick < rhs.mTick;
    }
};

typedef std::multiset<MyObject, MyObjectComp> MyObjectMultiSet;
```

or

```
auto MyObjectComp = [](const MyObject& lhs, const MyObject& rhs) {
                            return lhs.mTick < rhs.mTick;
                        };

typedef std::multiset<MyObject, decltype(MyObjectComp)> MyObjectMultiSet;
```

Comment: Ok. But once I got `std::multiset<MyObject, MyObjectComp> MyObjectMultiSet;`, where do I start to "insert" to this list? Should I init it before? I can't do `MyObjectMultiSet.insert(elem)` :(

Comment: @paizza Does it give you an error?  If so what error?  You may want to ask a new question though to resolve that as it will get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

The template argument should be a type, that is why you get a compilation error. This is how you should define `MyObjectComp` to avoid that issue:

```
struct MyObjectComp {
    bool operator()(const MyObject& lhs, const MyObject& rhs) {
        return lhs.mTick < rhs.mTick;
    }
}
```

or you could use a lambda:

```
auto MyObjectComp = []()(const MyObject& lhs, const MyObject& rhs) {
    return lhs.mTick < rhs.mTick;
};

typedef std::multiset<MyObject, decltype(MyObjectComp)> MyObjectMultiSet;
```