# How to use pmr vector with memory resource in structures?

Tags: c++, c++17

Following is my code snippet:

```
struct TestPMR
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<int> b;
};
```

I would like to use my own memory resource for vectors `a` and `b`. Something like a `std::pmr::new_delete_resource()`. Following code is the example for what exactly I would like to implement:

```
auto mr = std::pmr::new_delete_resource();
std::pmr::vector<int> a(mr);
```

Above code works well when used within the function like:

```
void dummy_fn(){
     auto mr = std::pmr::new_delete_resource();
     std::pmr::vector<int> a(mr);
     another_dummy_fn(a);
}

void another_dummy_fn(std::pmr::vector<int> v){
...
}
```

How can I use the same inside structure `TestPMR` so that all instances of this structure allocates memory in the given memory resource? I tried `std::pmr::vector<int> a(std::pmr::new_delete_resource())` and error occurs saying `std::pmr::new_delete_resource() is not a type name`

[typedef function is not a type name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746357/typedef-function-is-not-a-type-name)
This link did not answer my question.

Comment: Just use braces: `struct TestPMR
{
    std::pmr::vector<int> a{std::pmr::new_delete_resource()};
    std::pmr::vector<int> b{std::pmr::new_delete_resource()};
};` I don't see the point though - that's just a very elaborate way to declare normal, plain vanilla vectors.