# Error in set Declaration C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct StudInfo{                    //declaration of structure
    string name;
    int id;
};
int compareID(StudInfo a , StudInfo b){          //Compare function as a parameter 
    if(a.id == b.id) return 0;                   //that is being passed to the set s
    if(a.id < b.id) return -1;
    else return 1;
}
int main(){
    set<StudInfo> s(CompareID);
    return 0;

}
```

Inside the main() scope I am getting this error (error C2065: 'CompareID': undeclared identifier) Although this same code was successfully compiled 
in the video lecture in which this code was written Please help.

Comment: Upper versus lower case matters. Check spelling and casing again.

Comment: Your function begins with an lowercase `c` but you give `CompareID` which begins with uppercase `C`?

Comment: Also, look at the requirements for the comparison to be used in `std::set`. Yours doesn't meet them. It has to model a less-than type of comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Golden rule of programming: 99.9% of compiler errors are due to you, *not* the compiler.

> Although this same code was successfully compiled in the video lecture
>   in which this code was written

No it didn't!

How do I know that? Well, it's rather simple. First of all, I discount any possibility that the compiler is at fault. That then allows me to concentrate on the source code, *and* the compiler output.

The solution is simple: replace `set<StudInfo> s(CompareID);` with `set<StudInfo> s(compareID);`. Note the case carefully.

Compilation job done.

**Then** we can move on to your run-time behaviour. Your comparator function is not correctly specified; you need to replace the function with

```
bool compareID(const StudInfo& a, const StudInfo& b){
    return a.id < b.id;
}
```

The comparator must return `false` for all cases where `a.id` is *not* less than `b.id`. Note I'm passing the parameters by `const` reference to avoid unnecessary string copies.

Comment: Done, until the comparator issue manifests itself at runtime.

Comment: Doesn't the constructor need a functor instead of a function? Like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator ?

Comment: You can use a functor if you need require *state*, if you don't then a regular function is sufficient. The cool cats these days use lambdas.