# Error with custom struct: "VS 2015 error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Node'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, path-finding, a-star, stdset

I am attempting to create an implementation of the A* algorithm on a 2D grid and have arrived stuck at the point where I am needing to create a set of a node's neighbours. Below are the structs I am using.

```
// Holds values for x and y locations on the grid
struct Coord {
    int x, y;
};

// holds data for each node required for A*
struct Node {
    int type; // used for defining if this node is a blocker, empty, start or end
    Coord location;
    int g = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int f = g + h;
    Node *parent_; // pointer to this node's parent

    std::string debugmessage;
};
```

The error appears when I create this function here:

```
// finds a node's neighbours for A*
std::set<Node> neighbours(Node& n_) {

    std::set<Node> neighbours_;
    Node temp = n_;

    int x = temp.location.x;
    int y = temp.location.y;

    // start at the location belonging to 'n_'
    for (y; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (x; x < WIDTH; x++) {

            // east
            if (x < WIDTH - 1) {
                neighbours_.insert(astarArray[x + 1][y]);
            }
            // west
            if (x > 0) {
                neighbours_.insert(astarArray[x - 1][y]);
            }
            // south
            if (y < HEIGHT - 1) {
                neighbours_.insert(astarArray[x][y + 1]);
            }
            // north
            if (y > 0) {
                neighbours_.insert(astarArray[x][y -1]);
            }
        }
    }

    return neighbours_;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: So you read the [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) documentation and saw what it needs from the type it holds in order to function. Why didn't you include it here then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Many constructors (of the std) need comparison operators to work.

You use `std::set`, which dont know how to compare two `Node` objects.

As said in
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of
>   unique objects of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison
>   function Compare.

So you need to define comparison operator or give `std::set` a Compare functor as parameter.

The compiler tells you the first one missing: "<"

```
struct Node {
    friend bool operator< (const Node& _nLeft, const Node& _nRight);
    //friend not necessary since we use struct (full public)
    ...
};

bool operator< (const Node& _nLeft, const Node& _nRight)
{
    if (_nLeft.type < _nRight.type)
        return true;

    ...
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this is for an assignment that I am rushing to complete and I simply used std::set again because it worked in a different section of the code, where use of set was a requirement. Using std::list instead, also removed that nested for loop that was entirely unnecessary...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a std::set of something without overloading operator< or defining your own custom comparator. A std::set is typically a red-black tree with the objects being the keys, and that requires being able to compare the keys.

So either you make an operator< for nodes or you can make a custom comparator. Info on the custom comparator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator).

Answer (score 1):

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison function Compare.

[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

You have to overload the operator< for your node.