# How to define compare function for an array of sets?

Tags: c++, arrays, set, compare

We have a good explanation for single sets here:

- [Using custom std::set comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator)

but I wanted to know how this would work for an array of sets like below:

```
bool cmp(const pair <int, int> &a, const pair <int, int> &b) {
    if (b.first < a.first)
        return true;
    return a < b;
}

set <pair <int, int>, decltype(&cmp)> block[SQ](&cmp);
```

I prefer method 3 but you can answer any method you like.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. The comparison function is not a strict weak order.

Comment: `set <pair <int, int>, decltype(&cmp)> block[SQ](&cmp)` is invalid. I guess you meant to call constructor of `set` for each array element, like `set <pair <int, int>, decltype(&cmp)> block[SQ] = { set <pair <int, int>, decltype(&cmp)>(&cmp), set <pair <int, int>, decltype(&cmp)>(&cmp),  etc. }`

Comment: Yes I meant that; but how can I code that?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
struct CmpWrapper {
  bool operator()(const pair <int, int> &a, const pair <int, int> &b) const {
    return cmp(a, b);
  }
};

set <pair <int, int>, CmpWrapper> block[SQ];
```

---

As @SamVarshavchik noted in comments, `cmp` doesn't meet requirements of a strict weak ordering (e.g. there exists pairs `p` and `q` where `cmp(p, q)` and `cmp(q, p)` are both true). Using it with `std::set`, directly or via this wrapper, would exhibit undefined behavior.