# how to use a specific comparetor function with set as a class member

Tags: c++, class, lambda, set, decltype

i have have a class with a set of object pointers and i want to save theme in sorted order by their some field(id).
for debugging i simplified that to this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
struct c{
    auto comp=[](int* i1,int* i2){return *i1>*i2;};
    set<int*,decltype(comp)> seti(comp);
};
int main(){}
```

i searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator) to find how to sort them and i select the second approach(because i cant use c++20)
when you try to use that in main function or out of a class/structure it works.
but i want to use it in my class and i didn't know how to get

```
auto comp=[](int* i1,int* i2){return *i1>*i2;};
```

in class.i don't want to using a global lambda.

EDIT:
with `constexpr static auto comp=[](int* i1,int* i2){return *i1>*i2;};` compiler get this error:

```
m.cpp:4:27: error: ‘constexpr const c::<lambda(int*, int*)> c::comp’, declared using local type ‘const c::<lambda(int*, int*)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
     constexpr static auto comp=[](int* i1,int* i2){return *i1>*i2;};
```

Comment: I hate it when this happens. At `set<int*,decltype(x)> seti(x);` you've fooled the poor compiler into thinking you're declaring a function, not defining a variable. changing the braces up on the initialization should get things fixed up. `set<int*,decltype(x)> seti{x};` note the `{}` in place of the `()`.

Comment: For the first part, see if `constexpr static auto x=[](int* i1,int* i2){return *i1>*i2;};` inside the class definition does what you need it to do

Comment: Found the duplicate. Would have been faster to write the <expletive deleted>ing thing.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested fix, i.e. `(comp)` --> `{comp}`? Fix that, and if you still have an error, edit the question to just focus on that.

Comment: @cigien yes i edited the post tnks for recal that

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. However, don't just mention that the first fix works. Actually edit your code, and remove the first error message from the question.

Comment: @user4581301 i tried with constexpr... it doesn't works.

Comment: It looks like you're compiling with an older version. You need C++17 for this.

Comment: @cigien yes i compiled it with --std=c++11 and now it compiled by --std=c++17 without error tanks again

Comment: I'm sorry I left that Standard requirement out. Totally slipped my mind.