# Make set of pointers to use comparison criteria of underlying injects, C++

Tags: c++, sorting, set, shared-ptr

I want `std::set` if `shared_ptr's` to compare the pointee's, not pointers.
I have this example:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> s(new std::string("abc"));
std::shared_ptr<std::string> p(new std::string("abc"));
std::set<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> S;
S.insert(s);
S.insert(p);
std::cout << S.size();
```

As you can see I am putting the same element in the `set` but this outputs 2.
How can I make set's insert to use the comparison criteria of underlying strings?  And what if its not a string but more complex object?

Comment: What about writing a [custom comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second template parameter of `std::set` is the type of the comparator to be used (default is `std::less<Key>`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct deref_less {
  bool operator()(const auto& a, const auto& b) const { return (*a) < (*b); }
  using is_transparent = void;
};

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> s(new std::string("abc"));
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> p(new std::string("abc"));
  std::set<std::shared_ptr<std::string>, deref_less> S;
  S.insert(s);
  S.insert(p);
  std::cout << S.size();
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/Gr1K4q):

```
1
```

`auto` parameters for convenience with C++20, before the comparator is a bit more verbose. `using is_transparent = void;` to enable eg the `set::find` overload that accepts a `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` (see godbolt example).

Comment: "Missing" `using is_transparent = void;` :-)

Comment: `compare_shared` is not the best name (`compare` tends to return negative, null, positive), how about `deref_less`?

Comment: @Jarod42 didnt like the name either, thanks for the suggestion. I don't quite get the purpose of `is_transparent` yet. Found the templated overload for `std::set::find` that takes some param of type `K` that can be compared to `Key`s, but then do I not have to provide a `std::string < std::shared_ptr<std::string>` comparison?

Comment: Here, you might compare `shared_ptr` with `unique_ptr` with raw pointer. `std::less<void>` is *transparent* but you cannot compare anything with anything. So you don't have to provide `T* < T`.

Comment: @Jarod42 got it. Thanks.