# std::multiset intersection compilation error

Tags: c++, c++17, std, multiset, set-intersection

I'm trying to find the intersection of 2 multisets of objects using std::set_intersection function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>


struct Interval
{
  double bottom;
  double top;
};

struct cmp_interval
{
  bool operator()(Interval a, Interval b) const
  {
    return a.bottom < b.bottom;
  }

}

int main()
{
  std::multiset<Interval, cmp_interval> I1;
  Interval i;
  i.bottom = 20;
  i.top = 30;
  I1.insert(i);

  std::multiset<Interval, cmp_interval> I2;
  I2.insert(i);

  std::multiset<Interval, cmp_interval> I3;
    
  std::set_intersection(I1.begin(), I1.end(), I2.begin(), I2.end(), std::inserter(I3, I3.begin()));
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, i get a page of verbose errors that I'm unable to properly understand. I'm still a novice in c++ although i do understand some fundamental concepts. Below is the error log generated,

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -g /home/jamal/Documents/daa_assignment_1/measure.cpp -o /home/jamal/Documents/daa_assignment_1/measure
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/jamal/Documents/daa_assignment_1/measure.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) const [with _Iterator1 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Interval>; _Iterator2 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Interval>]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:5252:12:   required from ‘_OutputIterator std::__set_intersection(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2, _InputIterator2, _OutputIterator, _Compare) [with _InputIterator1 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Interval>; _InputIterator2 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Interval>; _OutputIterator = std::insert_iterator<std::multiset<Interval, cmp_interval> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:5307:48:   required from ‘_OIter std::set_intersection(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _IIter2, _OIter) [with _IIter1 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Interval>; _IIter2 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Interval>; _OIter = std::insert_iterator<std::multiset<Interval, cmp_interval> >]’
/home/jamal/Documents/daa_assignment_1/measure.cpp:338:100:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:43:23: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const Interval’ and ‘const Interval’)
   43 |       { return *__it1 < *__it2; }
      |                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/jamal/Documents/daa_assignment_1/measure.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:915:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator<(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)’
  915 |     operator<(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:915:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/jamal/Documents/daa_assignment_1/measure.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:43:23: note:   ‘const Interval’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>’
   43 |       { return *__it1 < *__it2; }
      |                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/jamal/Documents/daa_assignment_1/measure.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:922:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator<(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)’
  922 |     operator<(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:922:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/jamal/Documents/daa_assignment_1/measure.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:43:23: note:   ‘const Interval’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>’
   43 |       { return *__it1 < *__it2; }
      |                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Update:**
From the error log, I see that there's another optional argument that needs to be passed for `std::set_intersection` for custom comparator.

```
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:5252:12:   required from ‘_OutputIterator std::__set_intersection(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2, _InputIterator2, _OutputIterator, _Compare) [with _InputIterator1 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Interval>; _InputIterator2 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Interval>; _OutputIterator = std::insert_iterator<std::multiset<Interval, cmp_interval> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
```

The _Compare parameter looks to be by default
`__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter`. I want to use comparator class that i have made(cmp_interval) there but it doesn't accept classes.

Comment: You are supposed to overload `operator <`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You only need to do that for the default comparator. They have provided a custom comparator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have tried your suggestion, but it says that operator< has too many parameters. I guess it only accepts 1 parameter for the rhs of the binary operator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- That is for building the set.  For `set_intersection`, it knows nothing about `cmp_interval`.

Comment: @Jamāl `std::set_intersection` has an overload with a 6th argument for passing a comparator. You should be using that one, passing an instance of `cmp_interval`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I had looked up the use of operator() on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator

Comment: @Jamāl -- I know you used the operator(), but that is only done when inserting items into the set.  It has nothing to do with the `set_intersection` call.  See the previous comment by Francois.  You need to tell `set_intersection` how to compare two items.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux How exactly should i use cmp_interval in the 6th parameter?

Comment: Add `cmp_interval{}` as another argument and it should fix everything.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh wow, it worked like magic. Thanks. I hope to understand this maneuver one day.

Comment: @Jamāl `std::set_intersection` needs to know how to compare elements. Since you didn't overload `operator<` and are using a comparator instead, you need to provide that comparator to `std::set_intersection` otherwise it doesn't know how to check which elements intersect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::multiset<Interval, cmp_interval> I3;
```

Here, you specify the type of the comparator, as a type template argument. The actual comparator object is created inside the constructor of the `multiset`. Now you want to pass a similar *object* to the `std::set_intersection` function. Use:

```
std::set_intersection(I1.begin(), I1.end(), 
                      I2.begin(), I2.end(), 
                      std::inserter(I3, I3.begin()),
                      cmp_interval());
```

The empty parenthesis in  `cmp_interval()` mean: an unnamed default-constructed object. You could also use `cmp_interval{}`, since C++11.