# Comparator for member variable of type std::set that requires access to other member variables

Tags: c++, set, comparator

I have a class `ShapeDisplay` that stores a set of `Rectangle`s. I would like to store them sorted, therefore I use a `std::set`. My intention is to provide a custom comparator, which compares the origin (x, y) of the rectangle to a reference point (x, y) in the display.

However, in order to achieve this, the comparator needs access to `m_reference`. How do I use a custom comparator, that needs access to the class members? Is my design flawed? I know there are newer ways to provide the comparator as [in this link,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46128321/3021102) but that doesn't solve my access issue.

Alternatively, I could just have a `std::vector` that I keep sorted, such that each new `Rectangle` is inserted in the right position. But since `std::set::insert()` should do that automatically with a custom comparator, I would prefer that.

Thank you.

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Rectangle
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

class ShapeDisplay
{
    void insertShape(Rectangle rect)
    {
        m_shapes.insert(rect);
    }

    void setReference(Point reference)
    {
        m_reference = reference;
    }

private: 
    struct CenterComparator
    {
        bool operator() (const Rectangle & a, const Rectangle & b) const 
        {
            
            double distA = std::sqrt(std::pow(a.x - m_reference.x, 2) 
                                   + std::pow(a.y - m_reference.y, 2)); 

            double distB = std::sqrt(std::pow(b.x - m_reference.x, 2) 
                                   + std::pow(b.y - m_reference.y, 2)); 

            return distA < distB;
        }
    };

    std::set<Rectangle, CenterComparator> m_shapes;
    Point m_reference;
};
```

Comment: `set` sorts or free, but the way it stores data makes traversal significantly slower than the `vector`. If you do more traversing than inserting, easy insert may be a losing proposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CenterComparator` isn't related to `ShapeDisplay`, it isn't aware of its members and it isn't derived from `ShapeDisplay`. You need to provide `CenterComparator` with its own reference `Point`. You then need to provide an instance of `CenterComparator` whose reference point is set.

Note that if you change that comparator's reference point in any way you will break `std::set`'s sorting resulting in Undefined Behavior if you try to use it. So whenever `setReference` is called, you need to create a new set with a new comparator and copy over the old set.

Here is your code, adapted with these changes. I assumed you meant `setReference` and `insertShape` to be part of the public interface.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <set>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Rectangle
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

class ShapeDisplay
{
public:
    void insertShape(Rectangle rect)
    {
        m_shapes.insert(rect);
    }

    void setReference(Point reference)
    {
        m_reference = reference;

        // Create a comparator using this new reference
        auto comparator = CenterComparator{};
        comparator.reference = m_reference;

        // Create a new set
        auto new_shapes = std::set<Rectangle, CenterComparator>(
            std::begin(m_shapes), std::end(m_shapes),   // Copy these shapes
            comparator);                                // Use this comparator

        m_shapes = std::move(new_shapes);
    }

private: 
    struct CenterComparator
    {
        bool operator() (const Rectangle & a, const Rectangle & b) const 
        {
            
            double distA = std::sqrt(std::pow(a.x - reference.x, 2) 
                                   + std::pow(a.y - reference.y, 2)); 

            double distB = std::sqrt(std::pow(b.x - reference.x, 2) 
                                   + std::pow(b.y - reference.y, 2)); 

            return distA < distB;
        }

        Point reference;
    };

    std::set<Rectangle, CenterComparator> m_shapes;
    Point m_reference;
};
```

Comment: `auto comparator = CenterComparator{}; comparator.reference = m_reference;` can be simplified to `auto comparator = CenterComparator{m_reference};` which is basically just  `CenterComparator comparator{m_reference};`

Comment: Also you can assign the copy directly to `m_shapes`

Comment: Am I missing sth? It seems setReference is not called at all. It is not clear to when CenterCompare is called during insertion? In fact I run it and it is not called at all.  Moreover, setReference is not called as well.

Comment: @MaryamShabani `setReference` is not used in the code above, it is provided to match the context of the original question, which presumably uses it in code that was not shown. `std::set<Rectangle, CenterComparator>` declares a `std::set` which will use `CenterOperator::operator()` to know how to sort its elements. To see it called, you need to insert at least 2 elements in the set. Example. : https://godbolt.org/z/hfjn919x4