# Custom comparison for set accessing member variables of a class where the actual keys belong to

Tags: c++, set, custom-compare

How to specify custom compare for the following example? The idea is to access member variable within a class for comparison.

```
struct MyStruct {
    unsigned p;
    unsigned t;
};

class MyClass {
public:
    void call() {
        ob["o1_10"] ={10, 1};
        mbp[ob["o1_10"].p].insert("o1_10");

        ob["o2_20_2"] ={20, 2};
        mbp[ob["o2_20"].p].insert("o2_20");


        ob["o4_4_4"] ={4, 4};
        mbp[ob["o4_4"].p].insert("o4_4");

        ob["o5_10"] ={10, 4};
        mbp[ob["o5_10"].p].insert("o5_10");
    }
    
    
private:
    map<unsigned,set<string, Compare>> mbp;
    // Question: how to define compare using struct, operator(), statice metthod or external method so that
    //           compare fetches ob[ol] and ob[0l2] and decide based on some rules
    //           so, comparions is not based on ol and o2 and it is based on some p and t in ob[o1] and ob[02]
    // Eg:
    // bool compare(const string& o1, const string& o2) const {
    //     if (ob.at(o1).p > ob.at(o2).p)   return true;
    //     if (ob.at(o1).p == ob.at(o2).p && ob.at(o1).t < ob.at(o2).t) return true;

    //     return false;
    // }
    
    map<string, MyStruct> ob;
};


int main() {
    MyClass my_class;
    my_class.call();

    return 0;
}
```

It is important to note that comparison keys are not instances of the class. Instead, I want to use the key to access instances of the class to compare. If this can be achieved, I can save some memory.

I have tried the followings and each give me different errors:

1. struct within class
2. functor
3. using bind

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload `operator<` like [this](https://onlinegdb.com/wTrD60qU1).

With this operator you can use your class both in `std::set` and `std::map` (as key). In practice you probably also want to overload ALL compare operators ([For C++20 overload the spaceship operator instead](https://onlinegdb.com/SNW653i2q)).

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

class my_class_t
{
public:
    my_class_t(int x, int y) :
        m_x{x},
        m_y{y}
    {
    }

    friend bool operator<(const my_class_t& lhs, const my_class_t& rhs);

private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};

bool operator<(const my_class_t& lhs, const my_class_t& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.m_x == rhs.m_x) 
    {
        return lhs.m_y < rhs.m_y;
    }

    return lhs.m_x < rhs.m_x;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<my_class_t> set{{1,1},{2,1},{2,2}};
    std::map<my_class_t,int> map{{{1,1},1}, {{1,2},2}};
    int value = map[{1,2}];
    std::cout << value;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I think you're basically running into a wall here. std::set will need a function that is defined at compile time. What you are asking for is equivalent to set a compare function at runtime (different instances depending on the instances of your class). So it is kind of impossible.

Comment: So what is it you want to achieve, it seems this design is not going to work.

Comment: This does not answer the use case I am trying to highlight. The comparison does not happen between instances of MyClass. It is between strings. I need to access a member variable within my class. Please note that the solution provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639021/comparator-for-member-variable-of-type-stdset-that-requires-access-to-other-me does not work as well. Please refer to the post for my comment.

Comment: I kind of do understand your intent. I am telling you this is not how std::set and compare functions works.  The compare function must be known at compile time and cannot be modified at runtime to also get access to one of your class instances.

Comment: You asked a very important question (i.e., What is it you want to achieve).  I want to achieve optimum runtime for different tasks/operations run on my data (i.e., Collection of MyStruct instances). Something similar to https://leetcode.com/problems/max-stack/ . Thus I have two maps. Here I provided a simple MyStruct to highlight my point but my actual struct is heavier. I thought I kind of cross reference things so that I do not have to keep MyStruct instances  in both maps.

Comment: Does this make sense to you? What is the best solution for this? Any particular technique, data structure works better in this use case.

Comment: Never use leetcode as a source for code (just for algorithms). Code on leetcode is usually of very low quality and full of bad practices.  Well your code still does not make a lot of sense to me. But that's probably because in the end it is only filling some datastructure with so many indirections. ;)

Comment: In the end it is up to you to determine if it meets your requirements, write unit tests for your class and check if it does what it should do

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Perhaps I should share the actual code on github and request a review. Then it would be easier to discuss details. As for the original question. I got the answer that is not possible to do it as you mentioned ("I think you're basically running into a wall here. std::set will need a function that is defined at compile time. What you are asking for is equivalent to set a compare function at runtime (different instances depending on the instances of your class). So it is kind of impossible. ")