# Declare and define custom std::set comparator

Tags: c++, stl, set, containers

I have a class made (among others) of a `std::set` declared as,

```
std::set<customPair, decltype(comp)> mySet;
```

with (defined outside the class),

```
bool comp (customPair a, customPair b) { return a.first >= b.first}
```

and,

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> customPair;
```

Thus, in my `class` declaration, I declare `mySet` with

```
class Example:
  public:
    std::set<customPair, decltype(comp)> mySet;
```

when I write (i.e. define) it in my constructor,

```
Example::Example(){
 mySet(comp);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
   .../stl_tree.h:880:7 error: function  returning a function
    key_comp() const
```

I am wondering why:

```
std::set<customPair, decltype(comp)> mySet(comp);
```

does work when, for example declared on the fly in any method, but does fail in my case (within class)?

Comment: Initialize `mySet` in the [class member initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: instead of fragments you better post a [mcve]

Comment: @NathanOliver could you briefly expand what you have in mind :) ?

Comment: Pop quiz: what is `decltype(comp)`? Cheat sheet: it's `bool (customPair, customPair)`. When constructing a `std::set` specifying a comparator type of `bool (CustomPair, CustomPair)`, and taking no further action, has absolutely no chance of arranging things that will result in a specific `comp` function being called to do its task.

Comment: @floflo29 NathanOliver means for you to use this instead: `Example::Example() : mySet(comp) {}`

Comment: @RemyLebeau No alternative with a regular  Example() constructor as shown in the question (i.e. without using an initialization list)?

Comment: That is a regular constructor?

Answer (score 2):

The type of `decltype(comp)` is a function but the `std::set` comparator needs to be a function pointer or functor. Changing to `decltype(&comp)` fixes the compilation issue.

You also need to pass an instance of the function pointer to the `std::set` constructor otherwise it'll be null and will crash when you try to add an element. You can do this either in the initialiser list of each of your constructors:

```
Example()
:mySet(&comp)
{
}
```

Or directly in the class when you declare the member:

```
std::set<customPair, decltype(&comp)> mySet{&comp};
```

Note that due to a quirk of c++ in `mySet(&comp)` you can just use `mySet(comp)` and `comp` is automatically converted to a function pointer unlike in `decltype` where this conversion doesn't take place.

Comment: FWIW, the `&` in `mySet{&comp}` is not needed, but it is a nice reminder that it needs a function pointer, not a function object.

Comment: @NathanOliver yep, I do the same, helps prevent the compiler errors in the various places where it doesn't automatically convert like member function pointers

Comment: @AlanBirtles It works thanks. I have rather defined comp as a lambda function `auto comp = []{return...;}` thus `std::set<customPair, decltype(comp)> mySet{comp};` does work (without &). A last question: compared to a previous working case (outside class stuff), could you explained why `std::set<customPair, decltype(comp)> mySet(comp);` (i.e with parentheses rather than braces) does not work here?

Comment: @floflo29 in class initialisation can only be done with initialisers

Comment: @AlanBirtles ok but why the syntax with parentheses fails when set is declared inside a class rather than on the fly (I understand why initializing list does work)? Such as shown in solution 2 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator

Comment: because using parenthesis is not using initialisers. In class initialisation can only be done with initialisers