# What is wrong with the way that I pass comparator function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ by solving some leetcode questions. The question link is https://leetcode.com/problems/design-movie-rental-system/. I tried running my solution but it keeps showing a huge red block of error. My code is shown below. The logic might not be completely right but I am completely stuck on how to properly pass comparator functions. I surrounded the declarations that are causing problems with ***. There are no compilation errors but it throws errors whenever insert happens and the comparator is used. I used a previous stackoverflow solution to write this syntax ([Using custom std::set comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator))

```
class MovieRentingSystem {
    public:
    class Rental {
        public:
        int shop;
        int price;
        int movie;
    
        Rental(int shop, int price, int movie) {
            this->shop = shop;
            this->price = price;
            this->movie = movie;
        }

        static bool cmp(const Rental& a, const Rental& b) {
            if (a.price != b.price) {
                return a.price < b.price;
            }

            if (a.shop != b.shop) {
                return a.shop < b.shop;
            }
        
            return a.movie < b.movie;
        }
    };

    ***unordered_map<int, set<Rental, decltype(&Rental::cmp)>> movieMap;
    set<Rental, decltype(&Rental::cmp)> rented;***
    unordered_map<int, int> *priceMap;

    public:
    ~MovieRentingSystem() {
        delete[] priceMap;
    }

    MovieRentingSystem(int n, vector<vector<int>>& entries) {
        priceMap = new unordered_map<int, int>[n];
    
        for (vector<int> entry : entries) {
            if (movieMap.find(entry.at(1)) == movieMap.end()) {
                movieMap[entry.at(1)] = set<Rental, decltype(&Rental::cmp)>();
            }
        
            priceMap[entry.at(0)][entry.at(1)] = entry.at(2);
            movieMap[entry.at(1)].insert(Rental(entry.at(0), entry.at(2), entry.at(1)));
        }
    }

    vector<int> search(int movie) {
        vector<vector<int>> res = cheapest(movieMap[movie]);
        vector<int> vec = vector<int>();
    
        for (vector<int> v : res) {
            vec.push_back(v.at(0));
        }

        return vec;
    }

    void rent(int shop, int movie) {
        Rental rental = Rental(shop, priceMap[shop][movie], movie);
        movieMap[movie].erase(rental);
        rented.insert(rental);
    }

    void drop(int shop, int movie) {
        Rental rental = Rental(shop, priceMap[shop][movie], movie);
        rented.erase(rental);
        movieMap[movie].insert(rental);
    }

    vector<vector<int>> report() {
        return cheapest(rented);
    }

    vector<vector<int>> cheapest(set<Rental, decltype(&Rental::cmp)> &set) {
        vector<vector<int>> res = vector<vector<int>>();
        auto cur = set.begin();
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 && cur != rented.end(); i++, cur++) {
            vector<int> current = vector<int>();
            current.push_back(cur->shop);
            current.push_back(cur->movie);
            current.push_back(cur->price);
            res.push_back(current);
        }
    
        return res;
    }
};
```

Error display:

```
vector<vector<int>> vec = vector<vector<int>>({{0, 1, 5}, {0, 2, 6}, {0, 3, 7}, {1, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 7}, {2, 1, 5}});
MovieRentingSystem system = MovieRentingSystem(10, vec);
```

**Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**

I know this is a little overcomplicated for the problem but I want to know how to pass custom comparators properly and use them

Comment: `unordered_map` doesn't want a comparator. It's a hash table, so it needs a hasher. I don't see how that part compiles. Also, what's with all these nested containers? What's with the fixed indexing into some vectors? What do those things mean? I think your approach is way too complicated and you managed to confuse yourself.

Comment: [compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/7vvzhGTTG), please provide a [mre] including the full compiler error message. Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice especially as I'm guessing this is in a header file

Comment: @SebastianRedl the comparator is for the `std::set` not the containing `std::unordered_map`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ah, you're right. The nested containers confused me. Just another reason not to do that.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Keys need both hash and equality BTW.

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> vec = vector<vector<int>>({{0, 1, 5}, {0, 2, 6}, {0, 3, 7}, {1, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 7}, {2, 1, 5}});
MovieRentingSystem system = MovieRentingSystem(10, vec);`

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)