# Program crashes when using custom compartor for std::set

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, set, decltype

I tried to use custom comparator in a `std::set`. When I insert cuisine "japaneses" in a variable `bucketCuisines`, I get error DEADLYSIGNAL.

But, If i eliminate the custom comparator `cmp` there is no problem. But of course my results are incorrect.

Input:

```
["FoodRatings","highestRated","highestRated","changeRating","highestRated","changeRating","highestRated"]
[[["kimchi","miso","sushi","moussaka","ramen","bulgogi"],["korean","japanese","japanese","greek","japanese","korean"],[9,12,8,15,14,7]],["korean"],["japanese"],["sushi",16],["japanese"],["ramen",16],["japanese"]]
```

Result:

```
[null, "kimchi", "ramen", null, "sushi", null, "ramen"]
```

```
class FoodRatings {
public:
    static bool cmp(pair<int, string> a, pair<int, string> b){
        if(a.first == b.first)
            return a.second < b.second;
        return a.first > b.first;
    }
    
    unordered_map<string, int> bucketFoods;
    unordered_map<string, string> bucketFoodNCuisine;
    map<string, set<pair<int, string>, decltype(cmp)*>> bucketCuisines;
    
    FoodRatings(vector<string>& foods, vector<string>& cuisines, vector<int>& ratings) {
        int n = foods.size();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            bucketFoods.insert(make_pair(foods[i],ratings[i]));
            cout << "1 ok\n";
            bucketFoodNCuisine.insert(make_pair(foods[i], cuisines[i]));
            cout << "2 ok\n";
            bucketCuisines[cuisines[i]].insert(make_pair(ratings[i], foods[i]));
            cout << "3 ok\n";
        }
    }
    
    void changeRating(string food, int newRating) {
        int oldRating = bucketFoods[food];
        bucketFoods[food] = newRating;
        string temp = bucketFoodNCuisine[food];
        bucketCuisines[temp].erase(bucketCuisines[temp].find(make_pair(oldRating, food)));
        bucketCuisines[temp].insert(make_pair(oldRating, food));
    }
    
    string highestRated(string cuisine) {
        return bucketCuisines[cuisine].begin()->second;
    }
};
```

Comment: Having trouble figuring this one out, especially as the input supplied in the question is not in the same form as described in the comments.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. Include a `main` that calls the methods and produces the error

Comment: A side note: for efficiency reasons, your comparison method should get `a` and `b` by reference (or even better a const refernce in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data type `set<pair<int, string>, decltype(cmp)*>` is an odd way to specify the comparator as a function pointer. But that's what it does, and the issue is likely because you never provide a valid comparator when constructing these sets.

When you add an entry to `bucketCuisines`, you're currently relying on the default constructor for this set. But that will initialize the comparator function pointer to `nullptr`. When you go to add stuff to the set, the null comparator is invoked and your program crashes.

The simplest way around this is to make the comparator a *functor* instead:

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const pair<int, string>& a, const pair<int, string>& b) const
    {
        if(a.first == b.first)
            return a.second < b.second;
        return a.first > b.first;
    }
};

map<string, set<pair<int, string>, cmp>> bucketCuisines;
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch. C++11 changed things so that you cannot supply a comparator to any map constructor. This was news to me. Any idea why that change happened?

Comment: @john only the copy and move [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) don't have an overload with the comparator. What changed in C++11 is that there are also overloads for supplying the allocator without changing the default comparator

Comment: @Caleth also all constructors that take a comparator are listed as replaced in either C++11 or C++14 here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Caleth My mistake, I meant C++14.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, they aren't replaced, the numbers correspond to multiple overloads. That's a rather confusing layout, I admit

Comment: @Caleth ok, wasnt sure. Confusing indeed ;)

Comment: @Caleth Hmm, I tried this version of the OPs code `FoodRatings(vector<string>& foods, vector<string>& cuisines, vector<int>& ratings) : bucketCuisines(cmp) {` and I got an error basically saying that I couldn't convert `cmp` to an allocator. So I'm still a bit confused. (though I see what you mean about the confusing layout).

Comment: The `bucketCuisines` map is not the one that uses the comparator. The type of the comparator's parameters does not match the key for the map (which is a string). It's used by the set being stored in the map. Some typedefs would make this code a bit nicer to read.

Comment: @paddy Oh right,. Thanks, problems solved.

Comment: Thanks, @paddy I understand your solution and meaning. It`s old-solution. But i find C++ New solution in here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator   <- I checked this solution, but it doesn`t help me.  I used comparator only about SET, Not map. But Why the error occured? I can`t understand still

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I've re-numbered that page

Comment: @Caleth Wow, big improvement.

Comment: @EunnoAn Paddy's second paragraph explains why the error occurs. What about that explanation confuses you?

Comment: I have confusion about null comparator. Why null-comparator? I declared the function cmp, not null-function. I confused the relation between null-comparator and default constructor.

Comment: You told the `std::set` that its comparator is a _function pointer_ that looks like `cmp` or _any other_ function with the same signature. You must then provide the function pointer you wish to use to the set's constructor. You don't do this, and so the function pointer is null.

Comment: @paddy ```bool cmp(int a, int b) {
    return ...;
}```If this function ,  I can use ```std::set<int, decltype(cmp)*> s(cmp);``` this way either ```std::set<int, decltype(&cmp)> s(&cmp);```this way. But My source code has errored. Sorry for my low-level understanding.

Comment: @paddy I understand your comment above. But i can`t understand why these solution`s wasn`t working for me (Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator)

Comment: Post a new question. Nobody can know what you did wrong without seeing it. And this comments section is already ridiculously long and off topic. All I can say is what you did in _this_ question, which I already explained in my answer.