# Attempting to reference a deleted function, using set and custom compare lambda function

Tags: c++, reference, set, compare

I want to create a sorted list without sorting it by the sum of digits of each number. Therefore I chose a set, but with a custom compare function. I did not use set before, but I've read a lot about it and I thought it'd be simple to use, but I don't really understand my error: Attempting to reference a deleted function

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream f("input.txt");
ofstream g("output.txt");


int sumCif(int x) {
    if (x < 10) return x;
    return x % 10 + sumCif(x / 10);
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    auto cmp = [](int a, int b) {
       if (sumCif(a) < sumCif(b)) return true;
        return a > b;
    };

    set<int, decltype(cmp)>s;

    while (f >> x)
        s.insert(x);
    
    for (auto& i : s)
        g << i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add your code as text, not as images.

Comment: which version of c++ are you using?

Comment: c++ 14 I see, this is the prob lem ? :))))

Comment: I recently downloaded again visual studio, I didn't think it would use such an old version of c++

Comment: Look at Build Output, the error messages there are more informative. Post the error message as a pre-formatted text in the question.

Comment: What would really help if you have a bit of code (in text) that we can copy into our compilers to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620862/using-custom-stdset-comparator. Try the solution for c++11.

Comment: you must find the tab in your ide where the complete compiler output is shown. The summary in your screenshot is close to useless. Its a fancy thing that you can click and the IDE takes you to the line with the error. Your screenshot is not clickable and only the compiler output has the complete information. Please [edit] the question

Answer (score 0):

```
set<int, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp);
```

lambda disables the default constructor, so you need to explicitly pass the cmp