# Compiling MPC-0.8.1

Tags: gcc, installation, libtool, mpc

Following the instructions posted here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-from-scratch-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf

I installed GMP, MPFR, and ELF just fine, but while installing MPC with

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix=/apps/name/gcc  --with-gmp=/apps/name/gcc --with-mpfr=/apps/name/gcc
make
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -O2 -pedantic -m64 -mtune=k8 -version-info 2:0:0 -L/apps/name/gcc/lib -L/apps/name/gcc/lib  -o libmpc.la -rpath /apps/name/gcc/lib abs.lo acos.lo acosh.lo add.lo add_fr.lo add_ui.lo arg.lo asin.lo asinh.lo atan.lo atanh.lo clear.lo cmp.lo cmp_si_si.lo conj.lo cos.lo cosh.lo div_2exp.lo div.lo div_fr.lo div_ui.lo exp.lo fr_div.lo fr_sub.lo get_prec2.lo get_prec.lo get_str.lo get_version.lo imag.lo init2.lo init3.lo inp_str.lo log.lo mem.lo mul_2exp.lo mul.lo mul_fr.lo mul_i.lo mul_si.lo mul_ui.lo neg.lo norm.lo out_str.lo pow.lo pow_fr.lo pow_ld.lo pow_d.lo pow_si.lo pow_ui.lo pow_z.lo proj.lo real.lo urandom.lo set.lo set_prec.lo set_str.lo set_x.lo set_x_x.lo sin.lo sinh.lo sqr.lo sqrt.lo strtoc.lo sub.lo sub_fr.lo sub_ui.lo swap.lo tan.lo tanh.lo uceil_log2.lo ui_div.lo ui_ui_sub.lo  -lmpfr -lgmp 
libtool: link: warning: library `/apps/name/gcc/lib/libgmp.la' was moved.
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libmpc.a  abs.o acos.o acosh.o add.o add_fr.o add_ui.o arg.o asin.o asinh.o atan.o atanh.o clear.o cmp.o cmp_si_si.o conj.o cos.o cosh.o div_2exp.o div.o div_fr.o div_ui.o exp.o fr_div.o fr_sub.o get_prec2.o get_prec.o get_str.o get_version.o imag.o init2.o init3.o inp_str.o log.o mem.o mul_2exp.o mul.o mul_fr.o mul_i.o mul_si.o mul_ui.o neg.o norm.o out_str.o pow.o pow_fr.o pow_ld.o pow_d.o pow_si.o pow_ui.o pow_z.o proj.o real.o urandom.o set.o set_prec.o set_str.o set_x.o set_x_x.o sin.o sinh.o sqr.o sqrt.o strtoc.o sub.o sub_fr.o sub_ui.o swap.o tan.o tanh.o uceil_log2.o ui_div.o ui_ui_sub.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libmpc.a
/bin/sed: can't read /usr/local/lib/libgmp.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/local/lib/libgmp.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[2]: *** [libmpc.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/apps/name/mpc-0.8.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/apps/name/mpc-0.8.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any Ideas how to fix it ? It seems like it is looking in the wrong directory.

EDIT: after following the instructions linked to by Jon, it errored out after 3hrs

```
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
```

make[5]: *** [gnu/java/nio/charset.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/apps/ddechev/gcc47/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory`/apps/ddechev/gcc47/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava'
make[3]: *** [multi-do] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/apps/ddechev/gcc47/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[2]: *** [all-multi] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory`/apps/ddechev/gcc47/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libjava] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory

any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions you're following are not very good. See http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC for the simplest approach to building GCC.

Comment: Thanks, after running for about 3hrs, it errored out (message added to the original post) any ideas?

Comment: It could be that your machine doesn't have enough memory to build GCC, or it could be a bug.  Did it print anything else, such as the amount it tried to allocate? Do you need the Java compiler? If not you could skip building it with `--enable-languages=c,c++` (adding whichever other languages you do want, e.g. go, objc)