# gcc-4.9.2 installation failed on Linux

Tags: gcc, installation

The system information and installation command listed below [0, 1]. The message of `contrib/download_prerequisites` listed as [2]. Both configure.err [3] and configure.info [4] seemed ok. make_gcc.info can be downloaded from [5] and tailed 100 lines was listed [7]. make_gcc.err listed [6]. The installation command was checked by gcc mail list group and no error was found. But why it failed on my server? Any suggestions were very appreciated!

Best,
Pengcheng

**[0] system information**

```
[yangpc@node72 gcc-4.9.2]$ uname -a
Linux node72 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**[1] Installation command**

```
rm -rf /panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2
cd /panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages
tar -zxf gcc-4.9.2.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.9.2
./contrib/download_prerequisites 1> download_prerequisites.info 2> download_prerequisites.err
mkdir /panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-build
cd /panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-build
export LIBRARY_PATH=""
/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/configure --prefix=/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/gcc-4.9.2 --disable-multilib > configure.info 2> configure.err
make  1> make_gcc.info 2> make_gcc.err
```

**[2] contrib/download_prerequisites message**

```
./contrib/download_prerequisites
--2015-05-01 11:11:13--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2
           => `mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2'
Resolving gcc.gnu.org... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/gcc/infrastructure ... done.
==> SIZE mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2 ... 1077886
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2 ... done.
Length: 1077886 (1.0M)

100%[============================================================================================>] 1,077,886    510K/s   in 2.1s    

2015-05-01 11:11:34 (510 KB/s) - `mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2' saved [1077886]

--2015-05-01 11:11:39--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
           => `gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2'
Resolving gcc.gnu.org... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/gcc/infrastructure ... done.
==> SIZE gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2 ... 1897483
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2 ... done.
Length: 1897483 (1.8M)

100%[============================================================================================>] 1,897,483    816K/s   in 2.3s    

2015-05-01 11:11:59 (816 KB/s) - `gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2' saved [1897483]

--2015-05-01 11:12:17--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz
           => `mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz'
Resolving gcc.gnu.org... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/gcc/infrastructure ... done.
==> SIZE mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz ... 544950
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz ... done.
Length: 544950 (532K)

100%[============================================================================================>] 544,950      361K/s   in 1.5s    

2015-05-01 11:12:36 (361 KB/s) - `mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz' saved [544950]

--2015-05-01 11:12:38--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/isl-0.12.2.tar.bz2
           => `isl-0.12.2.tar.bz2'
Resolving gcc.gnu.org... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/gcc/infrastructure ... done.
==> SIZE isl-0.12.2.tar.bz2 ... 1319434
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR isl-0.12.2.tar.bz2 ... done.
Length: 1319434 (1.3M)

100%[============================================================================================>] 1,319,434    631K/s   in 2.0s    

2015-05-01 11:12:58 (631 KB/s) - `isl-0.12.2.tar.bz2' saved [1319434]

--2015-05-01 11:13:09--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/cloog-0.18.1.tar.gz
           => `cloog-0.18.1.tar.gz'
Resolving gcc.gnu.org... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/gcc/infrastructure ... done.
==> SIZE cloog-0.18.1.tar.gz ... 3857324
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR cloog-0.18.1.tar.gz ... done.
Length: 3857324 (3.7M)

100%[============================================================================================>] 3,857,324   1.43M/s   in 2.6s    

2015-05-01 11:13:29 (1.43 MB/s) - `cloog-0.18.1.tar.gz' saved [3857324]
```

**[3] configure.err file**

```
cat configure.err 
configure: WARNING: using in-tree ISL, disabling version check
configure: WARNING: using in-tree CLooG, disabling version check
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
     gnattools target-libada target-libgo target-libbacktrace
    (Any other directories should still work fine.)
```

**[4] configure.info file**

```
[yangpc@node167 gcc-4.9.2]$ cat configure.info 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin//install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
checking for gnatbind... gnatbind
checking for gnatmake... gnatmake
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... yes
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
The following languages will be built: c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... bootstrap-debug
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... bison
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for flex... flex
checking for flex... flex
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for expect... expect
checking for runtest... runtest
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for cc... cc
checking for c++... c++
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcj... gcj
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking for gccgo... no
checking for ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... no
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for readelf... no
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... host tool
checking where to find the target as... host tool
checking where to find the target cc... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... just compiled
checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
checking where to find the target gcc... just compiled
checking where to find the target gcj... just compiled
checking where to find the target gfortran... just compiled
checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
checking where to find the target ld... host tool
checking where to find the target lipo... host tool
checking where to find the target nm... host tool
checking where to find the target objdump... host tool
checking where to find the target ranlib... host tool
checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

**[5] make_gcc.info** 
http://pan.baidu.com/s/1pJA4xej

**[6] make_gcc.err file content**

```
configure: WARNING: In the future, Autoconf will not detect cross-tools
whose name does not start with the host triplet.  If you think this
configuration is useful to you, please write to autoconf@gnu.org.
configure: WARNING: cannot check for properly working vsnprintf when cross compiling, will assume it's ok
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/gcc-4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2'
configure: WARNING: fixed-point is not supported for this target, ignored
Links are now set up to build a native compiler for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.
../.././libiberty/cp-demangle.c: In function 'd_print_comp':
../.././libiberty/cp-demangle.c:4281: warning: 'saved_templates' may be used uninitialized in this function
In file included from ../.././fixincludes/fixincl.c:88:
../.././fixincludes/fixincl.x:79: warning: string length '667' is greater than the length '509' ISO C89 compilers are required to support
../.././fixincludes/fixincl.x:189: warning: string length '4756' is greater than the length '509' ISO C89 compilers are required to support
../.././fixincludes/fixincl.x:309: warning: string length '552' is greater than the length '509' ISO C89 compilers are required to support
../.././fixincludes/fixincl.x:354: warning: string length '532' is greater than the length '509' ISO C89 compilers are required to support
../.././fixincludes/fixincl.x:398: warning: string length '808' is greater than the length '509' ISO C89 compilers are required to support
../.././fixincludes/fixincl.x:527: warning: string length '560' is greater than the length '509' ISO C89 compilers are required to support
../.././fixincludes/fixincl.x:607: warning: string length '2768' is greater than the length '509' ISO C89 compilers are required to support
../.././fixincludes/fixincl.x:3741: warning: string length '729' is greater than the length '509' ISO C89 compilers are required to support
../.././libcpp/symtab.c: In function 'void ht_dump_statistics(cpp_hash_table*)':
../.././libcpp/symtab.c:290: warning: converting to 'size_t' from 'double'
../.././gcc/genopinit.c: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
../.././gcc/genopinit.c:517: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
In file included from ./tm.h:19,
                 from ../.././gcc/c/c-lang.c:24:
./options.h:4257:2: error: #error too many masks for ix86_isa_flags
In file included from ../.././gcc/tree-core.h:26,
                 from ../.././gcc/tree.h:23,
                 from ../.././gcc/c/c-lang.c:25:
../.././gcc/statistics.h:25:2: error: #error GATHER_STATISTICS must be defined
In file included from ../.././gcc/tree-core.h:29,
                 from ../.././gcc/tree.h:23,
                 from ../.././gcc/c/c-lang.c:25:
../.././gcc/real.h:85:5: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:85:5: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:88:6: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:88:6: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:91:7: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:91:7: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:94:8: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:94:8: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:97:9: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:97:9: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:100:10: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:100:10: error: division by zero in #if
../.././gcc/real.h:103:9: error: #error "REAL_WIDTH > 6 not supported"
In file included from ../.././gcc/c-family/c-common.h:24,
                 from ../.././gcc/c/c-tree.h:23,
                 from ../.././gcc/c/c-lang.c:27:
../.././gcc/../libcpp/include/cpplib.h:266:3: error: #error "Cannot find a least-32-bit signed integer type"
../.././gcc/system.h:506: error: declaration of C function 'const char* strsignal(int)' conflicts with
/usr/include/string.h:359: error: previous declaration 'char* strsignal(int)' here
../.././gcc/hwint.h: In function 'int clz_hwi(long unsigned int)':
../.././gcc/hwint.h:244: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/hwint.h: In function 'int ctz_hwi(long unsigned int)':
../.././gcc/hwint.h:258: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/hwint.h: In function 'int floor_log2(long unsigned int)':
../.././gcc/hwint.h:295: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/hwint.h: In function 'long int sext_hwi(long int, unsigned int)':
../.././gcc/hwint.h:328: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/hwint.h: In function 'long unsigned int zext_hwi(long unsigned int, unsigned int)':
../.././gcc/hwint.h:342: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/vec.h: In static member function 'static void va_heap::reserve(vec<T, va_heap, vl_embed>*&, unsigned int, bool)':
../.././gcc/vec.h:304: error: 'GATHER_STATISTICS' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/vec.h:312: error: 'GATHER_STATISTICS' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/vec.h: In static member function 'static void va_heap::release(vec<T, va_heap, vl_embed>*&)':
../.././gcc/vec.h:326: error: 'GATHER_STATISTICS' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/real.h: At global scope:
../.././gcc/real.h:51: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/real.h:51: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/real.h:76: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/real.h:76: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/real.h:76: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/real.h:76: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/../libcpp/include/cpplib.h:268: error: 'CPPCHAR_SIGNED_T' does not name a type
../.././gcc/../libcpp/include/cpplib.h:269: error: 'CPPCHAR_SIGNED_T' does not name a type
../.././gcc/../libcpp/include/cpplib.h:791: error: 'cppchar_t' does not name a type
../.././gcc/../libcpp/include/cpplib.h:802: error: 'cppchar_t' does not name a type
../.././gcc/../libcpp/include/cpplib.h:981: error: 'cppchar_t' does not name a type
../.././gcc/c-family/c-common.h: In member function 'omp_clause_mask omp_clause_mask::operator<<(int)':
../.././gcc/c-family/c-common.h:1131: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
../.././gcc/c-family/c-common.h: In member function 'omp_clause_mask omp_clause_mask::operator>>(int)':
../.././gcc/c-family/c-common.h:1151: error: 'SIZEOF_LONG' was not declared in this scope
make[3]: *** [c/c-lang.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**[7] tail 100 lines of make_gcc.info file**

```
tail -n 100 make_gcc.info  
            "" '' no \
            > tmp-mlib.h; \
        fi
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-mlib.h multilib.h
echo timestamp > s-mlib
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
                -o build/genattr.o ../.././gcc/genattr.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/genattr \
            build/genattr.o build/rtl.o build/read-rtl.o build/ggc-none.o build/vec.o build/min-insn-modes.o build/gensupport.o build/print-rtl.o build/read-md.o build/errors.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/genattr ../.././gcc/config/i386/i386.md \
          insn-conditions.md > tmp-attr.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-attr.h insn-attr.h
echo timestamp > s-attr
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
                -o build/genattr-common.o ../.././gcc/genattr-common.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/genattr-common \
            build/genattr-common.o build/rtl.o build/read-rtl.o build/ggc-none.o build/vec.o build/min-insn-modes.o build/gensupport.o build/print-rtl.o build/read-md.o build/errors.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/genattr-common ../.././gcc/config/i386/i386.md \
          insn-conditions.md > tmp-attr-common.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-attr-common.h insn-attr-common.h
echo timestamp > s-attr-common
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
                -o build/gencodes.o ../.././gcc/gencodes.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/gencodes \
            build/gencodes.o build/rtl.o build/read-rtl.o build/ggc-none.o build/vec.o build/min-insn-modes.o build/gensupport.o build/print-rtl.o build/read-md.o build/errors.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/gencodes ../.././gcc/config/i386/i386.md \
          insn-conditions.md > tmp-codes.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-codes.h insn-codes.h
echo timestamp > s-codes
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
                -o build/genconfig.o ../.././gcc/genconfig.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/genconfig \
            build/genconfig.o build/rtl.o build/read-rtl.o build/ggc-none.o build/vec.o build/min-insn-modes.o build/gensupport.o build/print-rtl.o build/read-md.o build/errors.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/genconfig ../.././gcc/config/i386/i386.md \
          insn-conditions.md > tmp-config.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-config.h insn-config.h
echo timestamp > s-config
lsf="../.././gcc/cp/lang-specs.h ../.././gcc/lto/lang-specs.h"; for f in $lsf; do \
            echo "#include \"$f\""; \
        done | sed 's|../.././gcc/||' > tmp-specs.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-specs.h specs.h
echo timestamp > s-specs
rm -f tmp-all-tree.def
echo '#include "tree.def"' > tmp-all-tree.def
echo 'END_OF_BASE_TREE_CODES' >> tmp-all-tree.def
echo '#include "c-family/c-common.def"' >> tmp-all-tree.def
ltf="../.././gcc/ada/gcc-interface/ada-tree.def ../.././gcc/cp/cp-tree.def ../.././gcc/java/java-tree.def ../.././gcc/objc/objc-tree.def"; for f in $ltf; do \
          echo "#include \"$f\""; \
        done | sed 's|../.././gcc/||' >> tmp-all-tree.def
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-all-tree.def all-tree.def
echo timestamp > s-alltree
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
                -o build/gencheck.o ../.././gcc/gencheck.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/gencheck \
            build/gencheck.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/gencheck > tmp-check.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-check.h tree-check.h
echo timestamp > s-check
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
                -o build/gcov-iov.o ../.././gcc/gcov-iov.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  \
                build/gcov-iov.o -o build/gcov-iov
build/gcov-iov '4.9.2' '' \
            > tmp-gcov-iov.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-gcov-iov.h gcov-iov.h
echo timestamp > s-iov
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
                -o build/genhooks.o ../.././gcc/genhooks.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/genhooks \
            build/genhooks.o build/errors.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/genhooks "Target Hook" \
                                             > tmp-target-hooks-def.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-target-hooks-def.h \
                                             target-hooks-def.h
echo timestamp > s-target-hooks-def-h
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  \
                -o build/genopinit.o ../.././gcc/genopinit.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/genopinit \
            build/genopinit.o build/rtl.o build/read-rtl.o build/ggc-none.o build/vec.o build/min-insn-modes.o build/gensupport.o build/print-rtl.o build/read-md.o build/errors.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/genopinit ../.././gcc/config/i386/i386.md \
          insn-conditions.md -htmp-opinit.h -ctmp-opinit.c
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-opinit.h insn-opinit.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-opinit.c insn-opinit.c
echo timestamp > s-opinit
build/genhooks "Common Target Hook" \
                                             > tmp-common-target-hooks-def.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-common-target-hooks-def.h \
                                             common/common-target-hooks-def.h
echo timestamp > s-common-target-hooks-def-h
gawk -f ../.././gcc/gen-pass-instances.awk \
          ../.././gcc/passes.def > pass-instances.def
build/genhooks "C Target Hook" \
                                             > tmp-c-target-hooks-def.h
/bin/sh ../.././gcc/../move-if-change tmp-c-target-hooks-def.h \
                                             c-family/c-target-hooks-def.h
echo timestamp > s-c-target-hooks-def-h
g++ -c  -DIN_GCC_FRONTEND -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ic -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/c -I../.././gcc/../include -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gmp -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/gmp -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/mpfr -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/mpfr -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/mpc/src  -I../.././gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/../libbacktrace -DCLOOG_INT_GMP -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/cloog/include -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/cloog/include -I./cloog/include  -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/isl/include -I/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/isl/include  -o c/c-lang.o -MT c/c-lang.o -MMD -MP -MF c/.deps/c-lang.TPo ../.././gcc/c/c-lang.c
make[3]: Leaving directory `/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/panfs/home/kang/yangpc/soft/lib/packages/gcc-4.9.2'
```

Comment: It seems to be similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255058/g-4-7-1-compilation-error-conflicting-types-for-strsignal May be you should try the techniques in its answer.

Comment: Thank you @HaochenWu, following your given links, I have successfully compiled gcc-4.9.2. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem has been resolved by unset the variables:

```
unset LIBRARY_PATH CPATH C_INCLUDE_PATH PKG_CONFIG_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH INCLUDE
```