# Switch between different GCC versions

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cuda

I recently built an older version of GCC and installed it in my home directory (spec. `~/local/gcc-5.3.0`). However, I need this compiler only for CUDA projects, and will be working with the system compiler (GCC 6.2.1) rest of the time. So, I guess I need to find a way to switch between these as and when needed, and in a way that also changes the library and include paths appropriately.

I understand that `update-alternatives` is one way to do so, but it seems to require root permissions to be set up, which I don't have.

The next best thing might be to write a shell function in `.bashrc` that ensures the following:

- Each call switches between system and local gcc
- Whenever a switch is made, it adjusts paths so that when local gcc is chosen, it first looks for header files and libraries that were installed by itself before looking in system paths like `/usr/local/include` or `usr/local/lib`. A previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708385/installing-gcc-4-9-without-root-adding-paths-and-binaries-and-extra) suggests that modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be sufficient, because a GCC installation "knows" where its own header files and static libraries are (I am not sure if it's correct, I was thinking I might need to modify `CPATH`, etc).

Is the above the best way to achieve this? If so, what paths should I set while implementing such a function?

Comment: My personal approach to this is not very sophisticated: I have a shell script that just adds the CUDA bin dir and the matching gcc bin dir to $PATH. Actually I have multiple scripts to keep different CUDA versions around. When I stop working with CUDA or want to switch to a different version, I open a new shell.

Comment: You mention adding only the `bin` directory of gcc to `PATH`. Isn't it also necessary to modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if not the include directories?

Comment: Both nvcc and gcc know where their libraries are located, so just changing $PATH is indeed sufficient.

Comment: if this is only for nvcc, then you probably only need the ccbin option in nvcc

Comment: Wouldn't CMake easily deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the above the best way to achieve this? If so,
>   what paths should I set while implementing such a function?

As others pointed out, `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are mandatory. You may also update `MANPATH` for completeness.

Rather than reinventing the wheel in `.bashrc` I suggest to employ a little known but extremely handy and modular [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) that were designed for this specific purpose. You could use them like (once you set up config for gcc/3.1.1):

```
$ module load gcc/3.1.1
$ which gcc
/usr/local/gcc/3.1.1/linux/bin/gcc
$ module unload gcc
$ which gcc
gcc not found
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty nifty tool to configure shell environment variables. Now just need to figure out how to actually write a module file for my purpose. Thanks for your help.