# How to install two GCC versions for cuda 5.0 on centos7

Tags: gcc, cuda, centos7

I need to install cuda 5.0 in centos7 x64. But, I have a problem with GCC, as the current version installed is (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11).
What is the supported version of GCC for Cuda 5.0 and how to install this older GCC version with my actual compiler ((GCC) 4.8.5).
Thanks in advance

Comment: `What is the supported version of GCC for Cuda 5.0 `  1. download the appropriate CUDA 5 installer from the cuda legacy toolkits page (google "cuda legacy toolkits"). (You won't find one for CentOS7, as it is not supported by CUDA 5). 2. Install it.  3. in the docs directory, there will be an install guide that lists the system requirements.  Read that and it will tell you what are the supported GCC versions.  How to install a particular GCC version on a particular linux distro is a question that has nothing to do with CUDA, and there are many tutorials and writeups that you can find for this.

Comment: I faced this problem of GCC when I have tried to install cuda 5.0, because it requires GCC 4.6 and I had already GCC 4.8 in my system. When I was searching in the net I have found both the two version 4.4 and 4.6. that's why I have asked this question to be sure in fact. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

@talonmies has provided a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6622751/1593077) of maximum GCC version supported by different versions of CUDA. Specifically: CUDA 5.0 supports GCC up to 4.6 - and that's what you should install.

There's an [answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-piece-by-piece-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf-without-shared-libra) which explains how to get GCC 4.6(.3) installed by building from sources. Essentially you need to build some libraries with any C compiler before you can build GCC itself.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much, You've been very helpful :)