# Unable to build MPFR on debian

Tags: c, gcc, mpfr

The environment is Debian. I was trying to build MPFR, but I was able to. / Congify ~ I was able to make a MAKE if I try to make a MAKE. How can I build it?[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-piece-by-piece-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf-without-shared-libra)

```
sudo make && make check && make Install


Making All in Doc
Make [1]: Directory '/home/usr/mpfr-4.1.0/doc'
MAKE [1]: There is no need to do with 'all'.
MAKE [1]: Directory '/Home/usr/mpfr-4.1.0/doc'
Making All in src
Make [1]: Directory '/home/usr/mpfr-4.1.0 / SRC'
../tools/get_patches.sh ../patches> get_patches.c || {rm -f get_patches.c; exit 1;}
/ bin / bash: ../tools/get_patches.sh: There is no permission
Make [1]: *** [makefile: 1744: get_patches.c] Error 1
Make [1]: Directory '/home/usr/mpfr-4.1.0 / SRC'
make: *** [makefile: 500: All-recursive] Error 1
```

```
../gcc-11.2.0/configure --target=h8300-elf --prefix=/usr/local/gcc11.2 --program-suffix=11 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch –with-system-zlib


configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: –with-system-zlib
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `–with-system-zlib': machine `–with-system' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ../gcc-11.2.0/config.sub –with-system-zlib failed"
```

Comment: What's with those random spaces in paths and weird wording of messages and random capitalization?

Comment: In addition to these random spaces and capitalization, you must *not* build software as root, thus must not use `sudo` with `make` (you may use `sudo` only for `make install`).

Comment: mpfr-4.1.0 : Use gcc-7.x.x or later. Also for gcc 10 , 11. ...... Build gcc with internal mpfr etc. : **10** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zIwm4j1obAPYbQqva9LDNMrvCpR39sgu/view?usp=sharing ... **11** https://drive.google.com/file/d/139Nmva_r4Y_nVEGaxghzD0um365qdTT_/view?usp=sharing ........ P.S.: Your "Reference link" is old.

Comment: I get an error when I try to do a config on the last build-gcc. I have made changes to the question text. What should I do?