# How to sort std::set according to the second element?

Tags: c++, sorting, stdset, custom-compare

Given `n` points in a two-dimensional space, sort all the points in *ascending* order.

```
(x1,y1) > (x2,y2) if and only if (x1>x2) or (x1==x2 && y1<y2)
```

**Input specification**:

The first line consists of an integer `t`, the number of test cases. Then for each test case, the first line consists of an integer `n`, the number of points. Then the next `n` lines contain two integers `xi`, `yi`  which represents the point.

**Output Specification**:

For each test case print the sorted order of the points.
Input constraints:

```
1 <= t <= 10
1 <= n <= 100000
- 10 ^ 9 <= co - ordinates <= 10 ^ 9
```

NOTE: Strict time limit. Prefer `scanf`/`printf`/`BufferedReader` instead of `cin`/`cout`/`Scanner`.

**Sample Input**:

```
1
5
3 4
-1 2
5 -3
3 3
-1 -2
```

**Sample Output**:

```
-1 2
-1 -2
3 4
3 3
5 -3
```

I declared a `set`, now I want to sort *descendingly(values) if the keys are equal*. Here is my code:

```
int main() 
{
    int n, i, hold = 0;
    set<pair<int, int>>s;
    int x, y, t;
    set<pair<int, int>>::iterator it;

    SF(t)
        while (t--)
        {

            SF(n) while (n--) {
                SF(x) SF(y)
                    s.insert({ x,y });
            }

            for (it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
                PF(it->first) printf(" "); PF(it->second); printf("\n");
            }
            s.clear();
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**my output**

```
-1 -2
-1 2
3 3
3 4
5 -3
```

I want the key values to be sorted descendingly if the keys are same.

Comment: What is `SF` and `PF`? Do you want the `set` itself to sort the values descending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set doesn't sort the way you want by default, so you have to supply your own comparison function.

```
struct MyComp
{
    bool operator()(const pair<int,int>& x, const pair<int,int>& y) const
    {
        return x.first < y.first || (x.first == y.first && x.second > y.second);
    }
};

set<pair<int,int>, MyComp> s;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) uses by default [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) as default comparator for comparing the elements inserting to it.

In your case, you have `std::pair<int,int>` as your element type hence, the `std::set` uses the [default `operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) of `std::pair` defined in the standard and hence you are not getting the result you want.

In order to achieve your custom style comparison, you need to provide a custom comparator

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
 //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --> instead of this
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

which should meet the requirements of [compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). 
Since C++11 you could also use a lambda function for this:

Following is a sample example code: **([See Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/db8aapvrwUxJ7mgN))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using  pairs = std::pair<int, int>;

int main()
{
    // custom compare
    const auto compare = [](const pairs &lhs, const pairs &rhs) 
    {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first || (lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second > rhs.second);
    };

    std::set<pairs, decltype(compare)> mySet(compare);

    mySet.emplace(3, 4);
    mySet.emplace(-1, 2);
    mySet.emplace(5, -3);
    mySet.emplace(3, 3);
    mySet.emplace(-1, -2);

    for (const auto& it : mySet)
        std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << std::endl;
}
```

**Output**:

```
-1 2
-1 -2
3 4
3 3
5 -3
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Jejo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57039715/10257651) and others have answered, you can create a custom comparitor to specify how you want your points sorted:

```
// custom compare
const auto compare = [](const pairs &lhs, const pairs &rhs) 
{
    return lhs.first < rhs.first || (lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second > rhs.second);
};

set<pair<int, int>, decltype(compare)> mySet(compare);
```

However, if performance is your concern, you will probably find that using a std::vector and calling std::sort is much faster than the std::set/insert alternative:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int n, i, hold = 0;
    vector<pair<int, int>> v;
    int x, y, t;

    SF(t)
        while (t--)
        {

            SF(n) 
            v.reserve(n);
            while (n--) {
                SF(x) SF(y)
                    v.emplace_back( x,y );
            }

            // custom comparitor
            const auto comp = [](const pairs &lhs, const pairs &rhs) 
            {
                return lhs.first < rhs.first || (lhs.first == rhs.first && lhs.second > rhs.second);
            };

            sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);

            for (const auto &p : v) {
                PF(p.first) printf(" "); PF(p.second); printf("\n");
            }
            v.clear();
        }
    return 0;
}
```

A couple reasons why inserting into a set is slower than inserting into a vector and then sorting:

1. std::set implementations involve binary trees, usually red-black trees. [See here for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2558323/10257651)
2. Iterating over the range of elements in a std::set is [much slower](https://tinodidriksen.com/2010/04/cpp-set-performance/)

Note that both methods require n allocations and require on the order of nlog(n) operations for insertion + sorting.