# Does std::sort implement Quicksort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [which type of sorting is used in the function sort()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840121/which-type-of-sorting-is-used-in-the-function-sort)

Does std::sort implement Quicksort?

Comment: Wikipedia indicates that the specific algorithm is not specified.

Answer (score 48):

There are two algorithms that are traditionally used.

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is most likely to use [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), or at least a variation over QuickSort called [IntroSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), which "degenerates" to [HeapSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) when the recursion goes too deep.

From the standard:

> Complexity: O(N log(N)) comparisons.

`std::stable_sort` is most likely to use [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), because of the stability requirement. However note that MergeSort requires extra space in order to be efficient.

From the standard:

> Complexity: It does at most N log<sup>2</sup>(N) comparisons; if enough extra memory is available, it is N log(N).

I have yet to see a `std::sort` implementing [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) which is promising and has been adopted in Python (crafted for it in fact), Java and Android (to date).

Comment: @maxim-yegorushkin: the Wikipedia article also appears to claim introsort switching to insertion sort instead of heapsort :/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(C%2B%2B)
    "The GNU Standard C++ library, for example, uses a hybrid sorting algorithm: introsort is performed first, to a maximum depth given by 2×log2 n, where n is the number of elements, followed by an insertion sort on the result."

Comment: Because `QuickSort` has a worst case of `O(N^2)`, would you mind updating the answer since that can no longer be used in a C++11+ complaint implementation?

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia -

The specific sorting algorithm is not mandated and may vary across implementations. [Sort Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28C%2B%2B%29)

Comment: While in this case it is probably true, I would be very careful about what I read on Wikipedia. When it comes to have a reference, cite the standard instead.

Answer (score -4):

I think so. std::list has a sort method, or you can call sort from  which takes 2 iterators, begin and end.

Answer (score -4):

because of high worst complexity of quicksort (N^2) and relatively tough to implement on linklist. I thinksort will not be done using quicksort

Comment: `std::sort` does not work on linked-lists, so it's a non-issue.