# Heap sort is not used in C++ library

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, heapsort

Since heap sort has time complexity of O(nlogn) in all scenarios i.e. best case,average case and worst case.
While quick sort has time complexity of O(n2) in worst case.

Then despite having less complexity in worst case, why heap sort is not implemented in C++ library instead of quick sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does std::sort implement Quicksort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038895/does-stdsort-implement-quicksort)

Comment: Heap sort is definitely in the standard library, and `std::sort` is always O(nlogn).

Comment: [Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) analysis is an analysis of the **limiting behavior** of a function or algorithm.

Comment: @Fanael Your statement does not make much sense.

Comment: **Heap Sort** is not an **inplace** algorithm. It always requires an extra `O(n)` space. Where as **quicksort**  is an inplace algorithm. You can improve the quick sort time complexity by using [**`randomised quicksort`**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomized-algorithms-set-1-introduction-and-analysis/). In which you can achieve [**O(NlogN)**](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35994/why-does-randomized-quicksort-have-on-log-n-worst-case-runtime-cost) time complexity.

Comment: Visual Studio implementation of std::sort is [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), which starts off with quick sort, but switches to heap sort if any recursion branch gets too deep.

Comment: @ishpreet -- that randomized quicksort is a pretty good demonstration of why time complexity is not the only relevant consideration. Each pivot selection requires O(n) time, while the usual quick sort is O(1). Sure, the overall algorithm is O(nlogn), but that hides the multiplier. If sorting 1000 elements takes twice as long with a randomized sort, then it's pointless to argue that for larger arrays it might be faster. Slower is still slower, and time complexity doesn't tell you everything you need to know. Every "improvement" I've seen to quicksort ends up taking more time for normal cases.

Comment: @ishpreet: how is heap-sort not in-place?

Comment: @nbro: what statement doesn’t make sense? Heap-sort is in the standard C++ library (although not under this name and needing two algorithm calls: `std::make_heap()` and `std::sort_heap()`). Also `std::sort()` is required to do O(n log n) comparisons in the worst case which is achieve through the use of [Introsort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort).

Answer (score 3):

Heap-sort is **slow** compared to quicksort. Of course, a vanilla quicksort is slow,too, but it can be made very fast by using insertion-sort and some fallback for the rare cases where a part of the range is suboptimal for quicksort. In practice `std::sort()` is a hybrid algorithm. For more details see my [Quicker Sorting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jz9xIfvAd30) presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Er, no, heapsort ***is*** used in the Standard Library.

The **introsort**, created *for* the Standard Library, works by being “introspective”. It sorts using a quicksort, but if the quicksort becomes too expensive, it switches to a heapsort.

**edit**

In order to improve an answer to the underlying assumption of the question, there needs to be made clear a difference between algorithmic complexity and actual speed.

**Big O, Big Θ, Big Ω**
The complexity of an algorithm (commonly measured using Big O and related notations) has little to do with the actual speed of an algorithm. What these notations represent is a relationship between ***n*** (the size of input) and the degree to which the algorithm’s computational complexity scales as ***n*** grows towards infinity (or anything sufficiently large). This is why you can throw out all but the most significant term in the complexity polynomial: as ***n*** grows large the most significant term dominates all the others.

Another way of putting it is that Big O notation tells us how much slower our algorithm becomes as the size of the input grows larger.

Big O is of especial interest because it represents an algorithm’s *worst case* behavior when ***n*** grows large. Any algorithm runs fairly quickly when ***n*** is small. If all you have are a few hundred inputs, an O(n<sup>3</sup>) sorting algorithm will work fine. But for any enterprise-level business application, with literally millions of data, it would be very costly to use such an algorithm. (It could even cost you your job.)

**Worst case ≠ normal use**
There is another issue. Big O only tells you what the *worst case* behavior is. This is where you need to understand the data that you usually supply to a function. If you can normally avoid input that causes worst-case behavior, then an algorithm with a poor Big O rating might not actually be that bad.

This is the case of a quicksort. Quicksort has an O(n<sup>2</sup>) behavior for the worst case — which can and does happen — but it also has the really nice property that the worst cases are a very small subset of all inputs. That is to say, *for any random input* (and that is important here), you are more likely to have a good-case behavior than a worst case behavior. This is actually a very significant property. Not all algorithms are this cool.

**Know your data**
Again, being able to control for the data you process is significant. Guessing, or making any kind of generalized assessment is just plain bad programming<sup>[1]</sup>. ***Always profile for*** **all** ***possibilities.*** Fortunately, quicksort and heapsort are both very old and very well-understood algorithms. They have frankly been studied to death. The reason we use them is because they have stood the test of time. Other algorithms have not, so we don’t study them much.

**But... unknown data?**
Quicksort has a very good behavior for most inputs. But here is the wrinkle: if we allow *any random input* we also allow *bad input*. If we presume that we cannot control for all bad inputs (because we are accepting *any* data), it is entirely possible for an attacker (or even just a poorly written input process) to give consistently bad inputs that bog quicksort down.

Heapsort, on the other hand, cannot be bogged down. It has a nice Θ(nlogn) operational complexity. (Remember that Big Θ is a very tight bound on both worst and best case behavior.)

**So why not just use heapsort?** Because heapsort is actually slower than quicksort for each ***n***. In other words, the algorithm does more stuff for every loop than quicksort; Quicksort is a very lean algorithm in comparison. So for even small inputs, quicksort does less work than heapsort, and is physically faster for every ***n***.

Computer architectures make a difference too. Quicksort also has a better cache/access behavior than heapsort. Heapsort uses random access across the entire input. Quicksort quickly settles down to work on only small pieces of the input at a time, making it cache friendly. (You can even offload the pieces to multiple cores for increased performance; something you cannot do with heapsort.)

Finally, quicksort can switch off to insertion sort for ***n*** < [50,100]. Heapsort cannot<sup>[2]</sup>. (And here again you see a trade off. For less than 50 to 100 elements, nothing beats insertion sort<sup>[3]</sup>, even though insertion sort is clearly inferior for even relatively small ***n***.)

**Introsort to the rescue!**
Introsort solves this problem by being “introspective”. It recognizes when quicksort has found a worst-case input and switches to a heapsort, thus preventing quicksort from degenerating into an O(n<sup>2</sup>) problem.

Notes:

1. I even just recently had someone give me grief after asking him to stop making generalized statements about unknown input probabilities here on SO, LOL. Generalizing about your data is BAD. Just say NO. ;-)
2. I keep making references to the inner workings of quicksort and heapsort. You should look them up. But better, take this away: O(n) only gives you one piece of information about an algorithm’s behavior. If you want to know how an algorithm behaves on your data, *profile the quiznak out of it using your actual data.* Then seek to control your data or choose an algorithm that better matches it.
3. Yes. Insertion sort rocks. For really, really tiny ***n***. Don’t forget it. The takeaway: it is okay to intelligently combine multiple algorithms to handle your data well. Profile, man! Just do it!