# Why did my program call the copy constructor several times?

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor

My code only reads in `Points` from a file and then sorts them by natural order (compare y coordinate first, then compare x coordinate), then sort them by the slope of the points to the second point.

For the first sorting, I overloaded the `<` operator and called `sort();`

For the second sorting, I created a function object which was initialized by the second point.

I rewrote the copy constructor of `Point` to find out any unnecessary copying and found out that I copied many times the second `Point` but I couldn't understand why. Could any one give me a clue?

Output:

```
C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop>test.exe < input10.txt
During initialization : 0
Input reading has complete!
Sort by natural order : (28000,1000) (28000,5000) (28000,13500) (23000,16000) (1000,
18000) (13000,21000) (2000,22000) (3000,26000) (3500,28000) (4000,30000)
During soring : 0
Sort by slope : copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
copying28000,13500
(28000,13500) (4000,30000) (3500,28000) (23000,16000) (13000,21000) (3000,26000) (20
00,22000) (1000,18000) (28000,1000) (28000,5000)
During soring : 12
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int times;
class Point
{
    private:
        int x,y;
    public:
        Point() : x(0),y(0){}
        Point(int x,int y):x(x),y(y){}
        Point(const Point& p) : x(p.x),y(p.y) {  cout << "copying" <<x<<","<<y<<endl;times++;}
        double slopeTo(const Point& that) const
        {
            if (x == that.x && y == that.y) return - numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
            if (x == that.x) return numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
            if (y == that.y) return 0;
            return (that.y - y) / (double)(that.x - x);
        }
        bool operator< (const Point& that)const
        {

            if (y < that.y) return true;
            if (y == that.y && x < that.x) return true;6
            return false;
        }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Point& p);
};

class cmpBySlope
{
    private:
        Point origin;
    public:
        cmpBySlope(Point& a) : origin(a){}
        bool operator() (const Point* left,const Point* right)const
        {
                return origin.slopeTo(*left) < origin.slopeTo(*right);
        }

};
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Point& p)
{
    cout << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")" ;
    return out;
}


int N;
vector<Point*> v;
void create()
{

    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < N; i++)
    {
        int x,y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        Point* p = new Point(x,y);

    }
    cout << "During initialization : " << times << endl;

    cout << "Input reading has complete!" << endl;
}
bool cmp(const Point* p,const Point* q)
{
    return (*p)<(*q);
}
int main(void)        
{
    create();

    int before = times;
    cout << "Sort by natural order : ";
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cmp);
    for (Point* p : v)
        cout << *p << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "During soring : " << (times - before) << endl;

    cout << "Sort by slope : ";
    before = times;
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cmpBySlope(*v[2]));
    for (Point* p : v)
    {
        cout << *p << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "During soring : " << (times - before) << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's not specified by the standard how many times `sort` copies its predicate. Since the predicate is an instance of `cmpBySlope`, and since copying `cmpBySlope` copies its `Point` data member, that's probably responsible.

Comment: Thanks,I can't understand why sort will call cmpBySlope so many times,because of recursion?

Comment: You can observe `cmpBySlope` being copied [here](http://ideone.com/xiQFzt).

Comment: http://ideone.com/UGpLy4 shows no copying of points by replacing member `Point origin` with the reference `Point& origin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the Point copy comes from the cmpBySlope object which hold a complete Point instance. The fact that cmpBySlope is copied multiple time is an implementation detail of the sort function.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1840131/109960) to see what algorithm might be used by the sort function. In both cases, recursion is used and since Compare object is passed by value, you must expect copies to be created.

Comment: Thanks a lot,quite helpful!