# What is the space complexity of std::sort in the C++ Standard Template Library?

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I always thought it the space complexity is O(1) but I looked online and it uses different sorting algorithms at different stages which has confused me, what exactly is the space complexity of std::sort and when are they different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the memory complexity of std::sort() and std::sort\_heap()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286612/whats-the-memory-complexity-of-stdsort-and-stdsort-heap)

Answer (score 7):

The "space complexity" of `std::sort` is not defined. However, it is not allowed to dynamically allocate memory (as it is not allowed to throw `std::bad_alloc` unless your types do when copied/moved). So the only space it could take up is stack space. And its allowed to take up however much an implementation desires.

`sort` tends to be implemented as some variation of quick-sort, so that tends to be recursively implemented, so it would probably use O(log(n)) calls on average.

Comment: And your implementation would know what the maximum possible number of array elements in the implementation is, so O(log n) is some not very large constant. In that implementation.

Comment: @gnasher729: "*And your implementation would know what the maximum possible number of array elements in the implementation is*" No, it wouldn't. `std::sort` works on any random access range, not just standard library containers.

Comment: Yes, but given random-access iterators, calculating the size of the range is cheap.

Comment: @MarshallClow: The size is dynamic, and therefore it is not a "constant", large or otherwise, as gnasher suggested.